# Oy! Animated ads!

Tags: support, status-completed, advertising

Stack Overflow delivered a little piece of coal to me, today (or I noticed it for the first time today). Animated GIFs as ads. Like, the old-school, flashy-flashy kind:

Here are two deanimated frames:

> [image]
>   [image]

The ad (sourced from [here](http://s0.2mdn.net/viewad/3656429/3-220x250_Join_rotating.gif)) flips back and forth a few times before settling on the first frame. This is the only ad I've found that doesn't present the little "like this"/"don't like this" thumbs, possibly related to its GIF nature (in Chrome 31. I can mark it down in IE 11, but I've restrained from doing so, for science).

The thought crossed my mind that this was malware, but I've reproduced this on my locked-down work laptop.

It's really irritating, flashing away while I'm writing an answer. Can we, here and now, say *NO!* to animated GIF ads?

Comment: Please, Jeff, [come back](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OfMOo.png)!

Comment: @Arjan the "no animation" policy is still in place, this was a misbehavior of the advertiser, most likely innocent mistake. It was fixed really fast, in the holidays, so thumbs up to the team! :-)

Comment: Yeah, @ShadowWizard, that's what Anna and stevvve want you to believe. Now, if Michael would not have been paying attention during the holidays, who knows what *really* would have happened... ;-)

Comment: Then someone else would've picked up the pitchforks, @Arjan. But seriously, as I say to stevvve below, I was pretty sure this was a mistake. Fixed, as far as I can tell, at 6AM in the morning during the holiday season.

Comment: (Sure, I guess my smiley wasn't too obvious. Maybe I should clean up the comments then, Michael & @Shadow? And indeed, kudos for the quick fix.)

Comment: Meh, it's Meta, I wouldn't worry about it, @Arjan.

Comment: @Arjan no, all in good spirit here. :D

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**We are explicit in our stance against allowing animated advertisements on Stack Overflow.** We do all that we can to prevent them from blinking and flashing and dancing in your face, because they annoy us just as they do you. Unfortunately, HTML tags allow the creator to update said tags on the back-end-- and occasionally they do so without letting us know.

I've turned off the relevant placements to avoid any further serving of the ad, and reached out to the client to make the necessary changes.

---

Update: I noticed the related top leaderboards are also serving animated, so those are off now too.

---

Update: Client has updated ads on their end to be completely static. Turned the ads back on. Please let us know if you see this issue again!

---

<sub>**Editor's note:** Animated ads were temporarily allowed during the [network-wide advertising test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network) from June to December 2019. However, the company has since reverted to the previous policy of disallowing them.</sub>

Comment: Double hat suits you! By the way what are "related top leaderboards"? Couldn't see any ads [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/braintree/topusers).

Comment: Ah, sorry for using the lingo-- when you spend so much time operating ads, it's second nature! What I mean by "related top leaderboards" is top leaderboards in the same flights (thus subject to the same targeting).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xHmQl.gif ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://media.tumblr.com/bf218405e151534e4bc83fd05d61b1a7/tumblr_inline_mssrsxeJ5N1qz4rgp.gif

Comment: <blink>thanks man</blink>

Comment: Don't you do it, @Jin. DON'T. YOU. DO. IT.

Comment: @Jin you mean `<blink><marquee>thanks man</marquee></blink>`? :D

Comment: Awesome, thanks stevvve. I may have laid the hyperbole down a bit thick, up there - just so you know, I didn't really think there'd been a policy change to allow *twitch* animated ads. Knew it had to've been a mistake.

Answer (score 10):

So from what I hear, SO isn't supposed to have animated ads at all, so one must have slipped through. I hope they get to the bottom of it soon, to know how it got past their filters.

**Can we, here and now, say NO! to animated GIF ads?**

Sure. It's called AdBlockPlus, but I prefer not to use the adblocker on SE on principle, even though I never click on the ads.

In all seriousness however, this can be really annoying, and I think one of the first no-nos of web design, right up there with no using `<blink><marquee><img src="animatedrainbow.gif"></div></span></imsoawesome>"` is no using flashy gifs. Perhaps a gentler transition would be better?

Or maybe just blacklist animated ads completely

Comment: I know you're joking, but I'd really prefer not to sic my ad blocker on SE sites.

Comment: Yeah, SE has helped me so much, I disabled my ad blocker on a site for the first time

Comment: OMG! `<marquee>` totally still works!

Comment: We shouldn't be serving animated ads at all as far as I know, so this normally shouldn't be an issue. These must've slipped by somehow. I'll check on it. (cc @MichaelPetrotta)

Comment: This is good to hear @AnnaLear and I hope you get to the bottom of this... and get rid of those insidious flashy ads.

Comment: @AnnaLear why not post this as answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because it wasn't actually an answer. All I knew was "uh, that shouldn't have happened". I pointed Stevvve at this post since he can actually look into what happened and fix it (which he then did).

Comment: @AnnaLear makes total sense... just hope you were gentle with Mr. Stevvve, after all he's currently blinded by his hat! ;)