# We're testing advertisements across the network

Tags: discussion, advertising, announcements

For several years we've had advertising solely on technology-related sites. But many of our sites aren't about technology at all, so we haven't sold ads for them. Traditionally, that hasn't been a hardship since Stack Exchange sites have required only a small investment from the company to set up and keep live.

However, as we've continued to grow, the resources needed to maintain our network have also increased. Thanks entirely to the efforts of the network's communities, we have become an amazing resource on the Internet.  Generating revenue from non-technology sites will enable us to dedicate more resources to meeting your needs so this is good news!

The test has been in effect since May 21, 2019, and our advertising team will be monitoring to see how ads are performing. We don't know how many ads will run on each site, we're testing different solutions. It could be just a few or a bit more. In either case, these ads will be carefully vetted and we'll be keeping watch to continue to provide good content.

If you see any ads that are inappropriate or have any questions about this experiment, please let me know by starting a new question and tagging it with [advertising](/questions/tagged/advertising). This is a work in progress and we are expecting a time of learning and refinement as we move forward.

A few things to be aware of:

- We've received reports about ads that redirect, and those have been removed.  We've also received reports about ads that are spammy and those too have been removed.
- If you wish to report an advertisement, please take a screenshot of the ad and paste the URL (if possible) along with the site where you saw it to a comment or answer.  I'll report it to the ads team and we can track it down to investigate.
- Some of the network sites will show more ads than others. This is not due to reduced ad privileges (which don't exist right now for the network) but rather to inventory allowances.
- This is an experiment that will take us to about the end of the year.  As such, we're learning about what advertiser networks will work for us and which can offer the quality of ads that we desire. I ask for your patience and understanding during this testing period.
- Due to an already existing agreement, MathOverflow will not be getting ads and is not a part of this experiment.

Thank you for your help in reporting what you see and for forgiving us of the mess as we do some remodeling!

Comment: Can we please get some concrete revenue numbers that justify having to put up ads on the other sites?

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog No, we're not going to do that.

Comment: If you tell people about the experiment won't people act differently and thus the experiment is not well done?

Comment: @Outsider: Strictly speaking, that is correct. But it's impossible to prevent people from noticing the experiment (what, afterall, is the goal of ads?), so it's worthwhile to have a place for people to learn about it if they are curious. A bigger potential problem is the [novelty effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_effect). When the novelty has worn off, there's a better chance to get useful data.

Comment: just a quick question. Instead of trying to rely on generic ads providers, have you even considered proposing ads space to actual companies that may interested to advertise here? I think Sony / Microsoft / EA / Nintendo etc could actually be interested to have ads on Arqade (and user would probably prefer those to an ads for some snake-oil... ). Same could be said for Canon /  Nikon  on a site like Photography.... Give the user info they can be interested in, and make those come from the actual producers.

Comment: I mean.. you already have the community ads program going on many sites... no one would probably get mad if you pushed some reasonable ads thru the same channel.

Comment: You may want to elaborate whether animated ads are considered inappropriate in general.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft two days ago they clarified [in comments of related meta discussion](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/were-testing-advertisements-on-the-workplace#comment19633_6157): "Animated ads will be allowed during the experiment..." (not that this makes me happy)

Comment: Why was my comment about malware serving ads removed? This is a genuine avenue for attacks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising. Since the ad networks don't stop this happening is SE? I come to this site to help me code against such things, not get infected by them. You already sandboz user submitted JS on SO - why not ads?

Comment: I rarely see any ads on stack exchange.  Could it be because the ads don't link stackexchange but to another FQDN?  I have filtering set up to let through trusted sites like stachexchange ( and other sites in the group).  I generally don't mind reasonable ads but if they are coming from a different FQDN then that is a real security/privacy risk.

Comment: @CraigHicks they are coming from the same ad networks that serve ads everwhere else online.

Comment: The same networks that use cookies to track you everywhere you go online. An absolute security and privacy nightmare indeed.

Comment: @razethestray - That's too bad.  With the specialized topics contextual advertising ought to be enough.  Like in the old days when newspapers printed ads.  Remember newspapers?

Comment: On the topic of deleted comments - if you have something substantial to say, posting an answer would be the way to go

Comment: "We've received reports about ads that redirect, and those have been removed."  It disturbs me that you had to wait to receive reports for such things to be removed.  What is SE doing to actively, rather than reactively, prevent misbehaving and malicious ads?

Comment: @Kyralessa We're actually doing a lot!  As a matter of fact, we are not easy to work with as we require a high level of performance from each network we've interacted with. From the networks we've had relationships with, only 1 (maybe 2) remain with us.  The others have been released due to not being able to keep up with our high standards.

Comment: @JuanM Hmm...well, I will be leaving my ad and stats blockers enabled:  https://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2014/03/why-i-run-adblock-plus-and-ghostery.html  You've already failed test #1!  It's 5 years after I wrote that post and ad server operators haven't changed in the slightest bit.  If anything, the situation is worse than ever because now you think you've achieved "high standards".  Your standards are clearly not even remotely close to the minimum standards where I'll consider unblocking SE.  This is a website security, safety, and DOM performance issue, not a monetary issue.

Comment: [Stackoverflow already has problems with their ads attempting to track users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386487/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio). What sort of protections will be built-in to this expansion in order to protect users against this sort of misbehavior? That is, what will StackExchange do to make it actually safe for us to view these ads in the first place?

Comment: @JuanM Clearly the standards are not high enough.  You guys used to have a very high standard: nothing but a static image (or text) was permitted, period.  No video.  No audio.  **No JavaScript.**  Now you're letting networks place ads with JavaScript on here, and we're getting the same malvertising that plagues the rest of the Web.  Well... stop it!  Put the standards back where they were.  No JS on any ad for any reason, no exceptions, no excuses.

Comment: I haven't actually seen JavaScript or video in an ad for several days.  Has anybody else?  If not, maybe that problem's been solved and we can turn our attention to other issues?

Comment: @JonEricson _novelty effect_ is when you change the design of the website. As far as ads are concerned, people just hate them at any point of time so it's pretty unlikely that they will ever _enjoy_ or _accept_ them.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think the issue (at this point) is that they haven't said "we won't allow JS or videos" (or at least not in a main post - might be lost somewhere in the comments certainly). Also, what level of animated ads will be allowed (as apparently they will be). I've already added SE to my adblocker and won't believe them even if they say so but posting that as an answer seems unnesscary (though it would be helpful data for the "experiment" - its not an experiment if you go full tilt that's deployment not testing - to know how many people have now added SE to blockers that hadn't before)

Comment: Despite the amount of downvotes on this, I'm very glad that Stack Exchange is still making posts like this and letting their users know what's going on and collecting feedback. While we may not _like_ the changes, at least we are aware of them and can let you know how they can be fixed. I was showing this post off to my family as one of the great things about Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ProQ well..... if it wasn't for users shouting at SE, this post would have never been posted. They were going to make this 100% silent without telling anybody about it, hoping nobody will notice or care. So no, I am not glad people need to shout and complain in order to get a response. It's bad in all aspects. If they would have posted this ***BEFORE*** starting the "test" things could indeed be very different. But they didn't.

Comment: @JuanM Will you do some A/B-testing in regards to the effect on usage of ad-blockers as well?

Comment: All the recent developments like the new and "improved" home page + the escalation of ads has me really worried for the future of a site and network I invested heavily in. Sad to see y'all go this way.

Comment: Huh, guess I'm gonna turn my adblocker back on. I trusted ads when they were handpicked by SE to be... not shit, at least, if not good. But after the tracking ad on SO and this post, I no longer trust SE ads. Shame there's no way to "subscribe" or anything; I'd happily pay far more than you'd get off me from ads, just to support the site. Maybe look into that, if you're so cash-strapped?

Comment: Another 3 down, and this question will be the most downvoted one on the whole site.

Comment: It's quite funny, reading the statement from @JuanM and the many answers provided by the people who actually generate the revenues for this site, I'm having the very same feeling I have when management of my company comes up with some dumb idea that will piss off the very people the company depends on.

Comment: @ProQ if they let the opinions of SE users go straight to the bin, posting this is alibistic at best. _Look, we let them know and we let them say what they think, we're not bad ! Yeah we did everything as we intended before the post, why do you ask ?_

Comment: @peterh nope. That's just the net score. The record is 506 downvotes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required), so 26 more to reach it.

Comment: As you guys at SE may have noticed, this question has been very heavily downvoted, along with some negative feedback provided. You should be thinking, _"Besides the ads in the first place, what can we improve upon?"_

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife - You may think that SE is soliciting opinion here but that isn't how SE works. Increased advertising across the network is a done deal and this post is nothing more than a placebo for the people that altruistically built the SE network.

Comment: @JuanM - Why is this posting only *Featured on Meta* for a small selection of sites (1 out of 5 that I frequent). It seems to me that the content would interest pretty much everyone, MathOverflow users notably excepted.

Comment: @Jeeped technical issue; when a site has a featured question in its own meta, there is room only for two featured questions from the main meta, sorted by date of getting featured, most likely. Nobody has selected the sites where it will show or not show manually, and pretty sure that's not even possible.

Comment: I'd rather concentrate on 400KB JS and 650KB CSS. Just by gathering all low-hanging fruits there I'd expect more monetary results than by assisting fraud markets with a network of small websites. Even utmost dedication at redesigning the website (kudos for fixed header that eats up vertical space btw) won't cut hardware or development costs when your core technology is jQuery.

Comment: @ShaWiz Since then, this question has won the cup also in your more strict sense. :-)

Comment: @peterh  sure, because for some odd reason they keep it featured, so more and more people reach it and cast a vote.

Comment: @JuanM, could you have a look at [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network/331429#331429) This behaviour still occurs.

Comment: Ok, so here's the new improved experience: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332747/non-tech-ad-on-stackexchange-site - food container ad on Physics...

Comment: This seems wildly inappropriate: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12674/31394

Answer (score 992):

**Please forbid animated ads.**

From the discussions on [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329547/162102) and [this Workplace Meta question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6157/325) (there are probably others), it's pretty clear that the community does not want animated ads -- especially obnoxiously-animated ones with lots of movement and eternal looping.

SE's longstanding policies on the sites with curated ads (SO and a few others) bar(red?) animation, for good reasons.  Those good reasons apply to the rest of the network too; even though the *mechanics* of delivering ads have changed, this aspect of our quality standards should not.  This announcement is currently silent on the subject of animation, which is why I'm raising this here.

(I've also seen one report so far of a *video* ad.  Video is a special (noisy) case of animation and should similarly be barred.)

Comment: If I could upvote more than once I would

Comment: Could I add, please for the love of all things good, don't do Taboola or Outbrain or any of those trash merchants. They constantly push out brain dead pseudoscience, gross out ads, pornography, borderline defamatory celebrity articles, and other horrible crap. These things are the scurge of the internet and are frankly hateful.

Comment: I'll respond here as I have elsewhere. Animated ads will continue to be a part of the experiment. We carefully watch these before they roll out to the network but some do get by.  There are limitations on the kinds of controls that advertiser networks provide and we are doing a lot of this in-house.  Asking users to report what they see is usually step #3 in a process that starts with heavy regulations on these ad types.  Because we require so much care, many networks are not willing to sign up with us - and we're fine with that! Again, we're seeking for benefit on all sides of the table.

Comment: @JuanM are you saying that "no animation" is still your goal but some will slip through because of the tools in use, or are you saying that animation doesn't violate your rules so long as (conditions TBD)?  Reporting is currently hard, so you need other review processes or to make flagging easier.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386487/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio

Comment: Repeat after me: AUTO-PLAY IS NOT OKAY.

Comment: @JuanM If you are using Google as you main ad provider, your promise to watch out for animated ads is worthless. Some of their ad spaces are sold to the highest bidder while the page is loading. Google also provides little control over what is displayed. I am also disappointed that you only posted here after intense pressure from  Workplace StackExchange. It seems your supervisors would have preferred this would have gone by unnoticed. All SE sites have  now been blocked and as I am migrating to Firefox I will enforce even stricter privacy controls on your domains.

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife You can always post a bounty on a good answer if you think one upvote is not enough.

Comment: @JuanM: if “*[animated] ads will continue to be a part of the experiment*” then adblockers will continue to be a part of my browsing process. Animation, autoplay and spontaneous noise is a garbage experience, and falls well below the standard SO set for itself on foundation.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I wonder if animated ads are [a particular sort of red herring](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505601/including-extra-material-as-a-means-of-distracting-from-primary-material) here...

Comment: Firefox has protection against media containing audio from starting by default. It won't do anything to ads (good thing we have ad blockers), but it'll incredibly useful if someone decides to push auto-play video ads with sound into production...

Comment: Animated ads -> https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/wriggleling-ads-on-sci-fi

Comment: @m69 I'm seeing that too now -- both ad replacement and animation loops, both of which add frequent, invasive motion to the page.  It makes it hard to use the sites sometimes.

Comment: And I'll be testing AdBlock Plus across the same network!

Comment: I've heard good things about uBlock Origin

Answer (score 418):

## Contributors shouldn't see these ads, especially if they're not content curated specifically for the topic of the stack.

You don't need revenue from impressions/click throughs from active community members. We already freely give you the content that's generating the ["100K page views per second"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network?cb=1#comment1075789_329770), despite being such a small, small footprint of the total traffic on the website.

In other words, you're already monetizing us and our contributions. You don't need to monetize us further.

"Reduced ad privileges" should be an absolute *priority* implementation for the rest of the network, and this ad testing should be *opt-in* for registered contributors. The only reason you need us to see these ads during testing is because the "drive by" traffic that will generate the majority of the views are by nature not going to provide the feedback you need to flag unsavory or malicious ads.

Comment: "and this ad testing should be opt-in for registered contributors" It's worth pointing out that the reduced ads privilege *already* has the baked in feature of being able to turn it off, for anyone who wants to support the site by being served the full ad suite.

Comment: @Servy Good point. But as this is an "experiment", I was thinking more along the lines of opting-in to beta testing. Consenting to being experimented on is, IMO, ethically different than OKing being advertised to.

Comment: It'd be nice if this applied network-wide, too.  I mean, I'm currently a member for 150 stacks, and that number seems to be growing all of the time.  It's annoying to have to re-earn the same basic privileges on site after site, and it'd be yet more annoying if doing so were necessary to have some control over ads.

Comment: There is truth to "if you aren't paying, you're the product" but SO does have great ads. And this website costs money to run, so ...

Comment: @Julie And they can get that money from the non-contributing visitors that outnumber the users a thousandfold. If I'd known that SE was going to use my content on not-tech stacks to make ad money, I would have reconsidered those contributions. I'm very careful with how and where I decide to provide content. Then to be punished with ads on top of it is like a slap in the face.

Comment: I agree with you in principle. In practice, are ads really such a "punishment"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit more a burden and a pollution for the mind. Cognitive load from ads is a poison.

Comment: @WebHead Well I mean SO has added ads to sites before, usually when they become sufficiently successful.  And they certainly never said that all non-tech sites would be ad free forever.  In the past they've just said it wasn't worth putting ads on them from a business perspective.

Comment: Ads, by their nature, are _designed to force your attention to them_. Especially considering that animated ads are allowed, and probably 0 limitation on how otherwise obnoxious they are. Additionally, they _heavily_ increase the load of the web page you're viewing and the number of trackers and cookies you're exposed to. So, yes, they are a punishment, whether you look at them or not.

Comment: I enjoy the ads on SO, there is a suprising amount of ads on topics I had to work on and nowadays hate... so whenever I see one, I chuckle and whisper "not today, [x], not today!"

Comment: Hang on.. _"In other words, you're already monetizing us and our contributions. You don't need to monetize us further."_ But they're not already! This proposal is how they do that. No?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They're monetizing us by displaying the ads, period. They don't need to further monetize us by (keep) displaying the ads to contributors (the "us").

Comment: @Web Head - Suppress ads for every contributor or a contributor that meets your conditions, and if so, what would those be? Lots of questions arise: 1) Will you require X number of answers? 2) What about questions - some may not see questions as contributions even though they are very important. 3) What if someone only votes on issues? That's still a contribution. ... It seems to me that if you eliminate contributors then you eliminate a large chunk of people, and you take a huge ad revenue hit. There should probably be relatively high bar to suppress ads.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the vast overwhelming majority of ads (well over 99%) are nothing but the lowest kind of filth. ;-{

Comment: @kraftydevil I think you're misunderstanding. I'm not saying "all ads, ever" should not be shown to contributors ("active users", whatever term SE uses internally), I'm saying **this _experiment's_  ads shouldn't be shown unless we opt-in**. This is not a final-stage implementation, it's a live _experiment_ with features that include off-site tracking of ad networks that have admittedly not yet been fully vetted by the company. The long-term solution is the "reduced ads privilege", when this is no longer an experiment. This test is ethically different than, say, testing a new page layout.

Comment: While I agree with the spirit of this answer, in practice, I'd prefer that contributors are **not exempt** from this **trial period**.  Contributors are more likely to give useful feedback, and so during this important calibration time, I'd rather see more ads and be given more of an opportunity to critique.  Though, after the trial period, YES give us our reduced ad privileges.

Comment: @TTT I cover that in the last paragraph `The only reason you need us to see these ads during testing is because the "drive by" traffic that will generate the majority of the views are by nature not going to provide the feedback you need to flag unsavory or malicious ads.`, but we shouldn't be forcefully exposed to those ad networks unless we opt-in and _choose_ to be feedback providers. The people that will even bother to give useful feedback is still a minority of active users, so the rest shouldn't be exposed merely to make it more convenient for those relatively few testers.

Comment: @WebHead Yeah, I saw that.  I understand your point, but I tend to think forcing us users to experience the terribleness that is advertisements here would be better for the site long-term.  Animated ads is a good example:  Those that really hate animated ads probably wouldn't opt-in, yet their vocal voices are the most valuable in expressing disgust at such advertisements.  Besides, those that _really_ don't want to see the ads can (probably) use an ad blocker.  How about a compromise:  an opt-out button after the first month?

Comment: @TTT I'm not sure anything is really going to be changed, anyway. The SE team has been pretty silent after the first 24 hours or so, leading this to feel like another one of their drive-by "we're doing whatever we want" announcements. I just felt it important that SE be made aware of some strong, reasonable objections to the practice and the way this was rolled out. This was pretty much a disclosure that they'd been doing experiments on us for 6 weeks already, and that's the way it is. I expect to be treated that way by the likes of Facebook, but I'm disheartened that SE would do it, too.

Comment: ""Reduced ad privileges" should be an absolute priority implementation for the rest of the network" But isn't this privilege already there in all sites?

Comment: @KolappanNathan No. It's right there in the question: `This is not due to **reduced ad privileges (which don't exist right now for the network)** but rather to inventory allowances.`

Answer (score 369):

> If you see any ads that are inappropriate or have any questions about this experiment, please let me know by starting a new question...

I am not quite comfortable with above. Using meta to report inappropriate ads sounds like a sensible idea at a first sight but the thing is, it was already tried with job ads at Stack Overflow and has proven to work rather poorly.

That prior attempt of handling ads issues at SO, it eventually ended in a technical solution allowing users to just directly [report inappropriate job ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356422/839601) - and, given that meta complaints essentially disappeared after this was rolled out, I would say it has proven to work well.

I suggest that this time, we just skip repeating that painful part of learning about how meta is a poor way to handle troublesome ads and proceed directly to the way that was proven to work so much better with job ads at Stack Overflow.

There is even a ready feature request for that: [Please give us an easy way to flag inappropriate ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329700/165773)

---

Given that experiment is going to run for over half year at multiple sites I would expect that effort invested in porting mentioned SO feature used for job ads will be sufficiently paid back.

Comment: I agree. If the ad is reported on meta, it gets more attention and that is the goal of an ad, is it not?

Comment: We're looking at the best way to do this.  Details to come.

Comment: Even better, why not curate the ads before displaying them in the first place?

Comment: @JuanM I am absolutely happy to hear that, but for the sake of the smooth use of the planned feature you better consider how it is going to interplay with animated ads. Voting on the [top answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329818/165773) strongly indicates that people will pass negative feedback for animated ads and you better prepare to handle it. (personally I would prefer animation to be just completely banned but as of now your options appear to be open in that regard so you may confidently expect some complications with feedback)

Answer (score 298):

I'm glad to hear that topical ads are still your goal.  It's obviously going to take a while to get there, so in the meantime, are there any coarser filters that can be applied?  Certain types of ads that are not *generally* inappropriate might nonetheless be inappropriate on *particular sites*; can we do anything about that?

Examples:

- ads for mail-order meat (like Omaha steaks) on Vegetarian & Veganism
- ads modelling lingerie, underwear, or bikinis on some of the religion sites (I have seen such ads on Workplace)
- ads promoting particular political or religious positions, well, almost anywhere but especially on Politics, Skeptics, and (other) religion sites
- ads for essay-writing services (i.e. homework sites) on Academia, Writing, and maybe language sites (we have some persistent spammers from these services; I assume they also do ads)
- ads for junk science, paid-entry journals, and the like on science sites

Since there is some level of implicit endorsement when a site runs ads, can we figure out how to prevent the eye-rollingly inappropriate "endorsements" on specific sites?  That bikini or suntan-lotion ad that's topical on Travel could be problematic on Mi Yodeya.

If you can't do per-site customizations of the ad parameters, is it possible to exclude sites from this trial entirely if they make a good case for it on their metas?

Comment: To be fair, I don't see much need for number two in your list on ANY of the site in the networks. I would really like to put a big no on some things BEFORE we start to get really horrible ads on sites like Anime...

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I'd expand that for points 4 and 5 as well; I think they're pretty much always considered morally dubious at best, (much like the "have a secret affair" type ads.) I'd hope SE would take a policy in blacklisting any such inappropriate ads across the whole network.

Comment: The criteria for identifying "junk science" would be interesting. I'm interested in hard science - eg [Science a la Popper](https://www.iep.utm.edu/pop-sci/)  where-ever it can be managed - but too much of our "Science" does not seem to care about falsifiability or experiment or ... . Too many of the "currently rteceived truth gate keepers" are prepared to bar Science that is "as real as it gets" for whatever reason.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I don't know how to specify those criteria either, but I suspect that people on the affected communities do.  If we let communities say "these kinds of ads are not ok *here*", and if SE will honor it, then we don't need to work out all the rules centrally.

Comment: Do journals with an open-access article publishing fee count as "paid-entry journals"?

Comment: @DamianYerrick I'm imagining that the members of each community would be able to say which journals are legit and which are fake.  I don't know myself; I've just heard people talk about the problem.

Comment: I feel like ads modelling lingerie, underwear, or bikinis shouldn't really be on Workplace either... keep it professional

Comment: I feel like any NSFW ads should not be on the network. A lot of people use all of the SE sites at work.

Comment: @Magisch The concept of NSFW is too fuzzy and culture dependent to be any useful in a global context.

Comment: While imperfect, there are _obvious_ lines for NSFW that do work globally and have done so for decades

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano As Lightess pointed out, there are some things which are nearly universally unacceptable at office environment, such as for instance lingerie advertisements. Such should not be shown at least on any work related SE stacks.

Comment: @Magisch Given the number of mechanical workshops where you can still find calendars of naked women hanging on the walls, I keep my claim that there's no such thing as a universally accepted concept of NSFW. And, personally, I find lingerie ads as much as inappropriate as car ads, since I don't need any of them.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano You're right of course, but this network's demographics are inextricably linked with IT office workers. Even sites that have nothing to do with either have a much higher concentration of IT office workers then elsewhere on the topic. So it's fair to expect some concessions in forms of ad choices for that respect.

Comment: @Magisch One of my pet peeves of these communities is the assumption that everyone is an IT office worker (if I'm not much mistaken there have been already complaints about this on Workplace SE, isn't it?). For instance, even though I spend long hours in front of the computer, I'm not an IT office worker, and as such probably many others. No one in my office would be offended by a lingerie ad as such, but everyone would feel annoyed because of it's irrelevance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See my comments above. Note also that I've been around for a few decades now, and I'm quite sure that decades ago there weren't obvious lines for NSFW.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Of course there were. Just one example: naked people. It's not that you couldn't find any workplace where it might already exist; it's that this was a widely established "this is NSFW" line on the internet. Disagree?

Comment: Please take the discussion of what is or isn't safe for work in various workplaces throughout the world to chat.  Thank you.

Comment: Wait, is your implication that (1) ads for fraud aid (= essay writing services) and (2) ads for junk science are appropriate *anywhere*, apart from narrow restrictions? If so I vehemently disagree. This kind of ads should (obviously, duh) be filtered everywhere. One aids in committing fraud, the other *is* fraud.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ads for essay-writing services might be legitimate in non-homework situations, like hiring a subcontractor to research and write articles for your site.  (I don't know, not having investigated such services.)  What I (and I suspect you) call junk science has its adherents too, and maybe there are contexts where those ads wouldn't be inappropriate (on sites about whatever shared context the adherents have).  I'm not trying to defend either type of ad and would be happy to see them gone; I just didn't feel I could say they're globally wrong with what I do/don't know about them.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Eh. All I can say about the pseudoscience is: I’ll take “false balance for 500 please, Alex”. There aren’t two [equally valid] sides to every controversy. Everybody pretending otherwise is *tiring*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've got no use for pseudoscience either, and I won't be sad if the answer turns out to be to exclude all such ads.  I'm not that involved in the controversies around this (including arguments over what is/isn't pseudoscience).

Answer (score 165):

I am quite sorry, but I don't think I can help you at these conditions.

Please don't get me wrong, but as I read this announcement I can't help but to get a "let's try an see what happens, maybe they won't get too angry" vibe - I really don't get how much research has been done BEFORE and how much you expect to learn from the users having to face actual *incidents*.

> we're learning about what advertiser networks will work for us and which can offer the quality of ads that we desire.

By this claim, it seems you are still trying to learn what ads provider are working for you. Luckily enough, it seems we agree on the basis of which ads are just intolerable.

> Inappropriate ads are full screen takeovers, punch the monkey, scam, pornographic, racist, etc. Some divergence from topic is ok but we'll monitor for exaggerations.

While this is indeed good to hear, the mere fact we are considering the eventuality of things like these is quite worrisome to me. I would love to think this is just an hyperbole, an extreme example of a "will never be" incident that could happen to the best of the provider, but from what I heard so far I am not sure. Some users like Monica had to see lingerie ads on "The Workplace"... Really???

I will be quite frank. I am used to see a lot of ads pushed to mobile "freemium games" - being the tech pony means that every time a relative or friend notices something odd you will be the one that  will be asked for suggestion.
I always wondered... why some companies that produce pegi-3 games are somehow able to get trustworthy kid-safe ads provider straight from the start and some other producers strive to understand that online casinos advertisement in a game meant for kids probably isn't very appropriate. Why some managed to just use "safe" providers from the beginning while other are still learning what to use after years... I don't know.

I am not sure that some providers are really deserving to be checked in the first place, especially on a network like SE. While I totally understand your needs, I somehow feel the approach here is a little too much on the "reactive side". As far as I get it:

- multiple providers are being tested, but I can't access a list of the ones under scrutiny to see if we are talking of high-quality established ones or high-paying scammy-looking keep-changing-names-every-two-weeks malwertising factories. So far, the empirical data I get from some really bad samples that were posted seems to indicate that at least part of them are more close to the second option.
- I can't know **where** they are being tested, so basically it is a "can came up at any time" situation. That means that from my viewpoint it is useless to try to do some testing since I would just lose my time trying to even decide where I should be doing the testing in the first place (apparently, some sites are getting worse ads that others, so not each site is equally significant. Also, geo-localization seems to be a big part of the issue since I seem to receive far less scam ads that users like ShadowWizard do)
- I really hope this is just me being pessimistic but I also get a very unsettling "we are still testing which providers work for use, know that some of them could be serving bad stuff since **we don't know**" vibe. Yep, right, we are told to flag the bad content and so far it worked for fixing the errors... but I am not sure I want to be the one who will get the honor to report the adult site advertisement they got while at work or the one ads who tried to silently download a nice Trojan on their home computer.

Again, don't get me wrong, I know you need the money and I would love to get you some in some way. But as now, I am not sure I can really see myself taking part in this test.

It is time for some filtering.

---

**Update 1 July 2019:** in the latest days I have collected some info on the various incidents that have happened in just about two weeks of testing.

- I have personally witnessed ads that [attempted full page redirects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329547/ads-on-se-sites-are-excessively-animated-irrelevant-dubious-and-resource-inten/329614#329614)
- Some users on the SO Meta reported [ads that apparently use the browser's audio API for tracking/fingerprinting purposes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386487/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio)
- [Many users have been exposed to scam/clickbait ads](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/i-see-clickbait-ads)
- apparently at least one user saw an ads that attempted [to trick her into downloading an executable file](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/151?m=50759674#50759674)

I am pretty sure all those incidents have been resolved or are being worked on right now... But how can I be sure it is safe to drop the shield and check if the rain of arrow has indeed ended?

Comment: any ad provider that pushes ads like you mention in your (predated?) update should be instantly removed. Not just that ad, but the provider pushing the ad should be considered the vector for attempted malware distribution and blacklisted. And their names be made public.

Comment: and thanks to @jwenting for noticing too.

Answer (score 155):

Stack Exchange sites are the only sites I have ever whitelisted in my ad blocker. The second I see an animation, I'm going to block all your ads. Your choice.

Comment: Probably the answer I most resonate with, aside from generally removing adds for active contributors. It is an honest statement without any threat - a matter of fact.

Comment: Or running any JavaScript, playing any audio, making any popups, hijacking any portion of the page outside of its specific box, in any way whatsoever beaconing, redirecting, or... (All things, mind you, that ads _currently do_.)

Answer (score 119):

It seems that this system into which I have been investing my time, mostly by answering questions, has taken an important pivot in the business model.

I understand that organizations need revenue.  I understand that although I thought of it as "investing", and I have spent many days learning the community standards and working within the communities here, these "investments" have no weight in the economic decision.

I also understand that we, management and the contributing user base, have built a brand, a powerful reputation, and a market presence.  Also, that blank screen space is a tempting placement for ads, and that you, the economic owner of this space, have the means to open that blank space to ads and monetize the goodwill we all have accrued.

Nevertheless, even with all my understand and compassion, it is a loss.  It is another great, cooperative, Internet venue turned into a revenue engine.  This may be your only option.  Supporting this operation is expensive.  When I saw the announcement of the enterprise version, "Teams", I was pleased that you had found a way to thread the economic needle.

I read this move as an indication that "Teams" is failing.

This may be a move of desperation, in which case please communicate that.  It may be that the earlier placement of community ads was a strategic probe and the good words that came with it was a deliberate manipulation and deception -- management clothing itself in a shining mantle of virtue.  With the ambient cynicism in my world, without testable, transparent communication from management, it is difficult for me to take another view.

This is your site, and you may do as you wish.  My loss is the illusion that I was a valued part of it.

Is the day coming when answers are presented, one per page, starting with the least up-voted, surrounded by ads and encouraging notes that the best answer lies just ahead, through the next click?

Comment: "starting with the least up-voted" - maybe that's why SE has such high standards on what kind of non-answers it's willing to delete.

Comment: @alephzero I've been around a long time and have been the dasher and the dashed many times.  I was enjoying the ambience and the feeling of community.  I know it was an illusion, but I enjoyed it and through it I found pleasure here.  That may change.  Such is the way of life.  I am "used to it", but I wanted to communicate to management that there is a pain of loss they are causing, and not only outrage at content and so on.

Comment: I think more that just Teams is failing. To be, this is decision is more than a red flag, and more of a burning inferno of a signal fire. 18 months ago there was a 20% reduction in staff. A few months before that, Documentation was sunsetted. And a few months before that, shut down Blog Overflow. Teams hasn't appeared to pull in enough revenue, and Careers is apparently not enough to maintain.

Comment: This is just all sorts of wrong. We've been serving advertisements since almost the beginning of the network. This test is an attempt to find a way to expand that to all sites on the network, where we were previously unable to serve them because of the site topics. Nothing is failing, and trying to frame this as the beginning of the end is just plain unconstructive here. (PS, there's even a [list of sites that had advertisements enabled before this test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243364).)

Comment: @animuson This is, however, only half the truth either, though. May this answer be a little hyperbolic, but this test doesn't *just* mark the arrival of SE ads on other sites but *also*, as measured by the content of the served ads, a stark departure from SE's previous ad philosophy. So yes, SE has served ads in the past, but certainly not *such* ads. Of course it in fact doesn't mean a difference for SO (the site), but SO is largely peripheral to this discussion.

Comment: @ChristianRau Our philosophies have not changed at all. The entire point of the experiment is to determine if there are possibilities out there that match our philosophies. We are very much *not* attempting to downgrade quality of ads.

Comment: @animuson If nothing is failing, then why is SO's ad revenue suddenly **not** ["enough"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217832/287266)?

Comment: @animuson Then you may want to clarify this a little more in the announcement, since from things like e.g. off-topic and excessivley animated ads being seen as "appropriate" in the test, one would easily conclude that they're appropriate for the test's *result*, too, will *definitely* be a change to SE's ad philosophy. So far noone has clarified yet, if e.g. a resource heavy animated ad for an online casino is okay for SciFi.SE. If it is, then that *is* a departure from the ad philosophy. If it only is for the test but somehow not for what commences thereafter, this would be important to know.

Comment: @WebHead I suspect, rather than things "failing" as such, SO's private investors have come calling, and its time to pay the piper, as it were. Cut costs, bump revenue, demonstrate growth, get the thing in shape for an IPO so people can cash out before the current US business cycle slows down (maybe the yield curve has put people a little on edge).

Comment: Related: *[A World of Endless Advertisements](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-world-of-endless-advertisements/)* (by one of the founders of Stack Overflow)

Comment: _"This may be a move of desperation, in which case please communicate that."_ Why on earth would anyone do that?

Comment: Communicating desperation makes the product totally unacceptable for all the businesses that could have opted to invest into it, because it signifies "end of life" stage of the project and its soonest departure from the market. Before desperation is communicated, such project can still be salvaged by a smart business idea.

Comment: "Desparation" is a strong word, and probably not felt as such in the board room.  To users who expect a certain moral contract with the company, a change in that contract feels like either moral flippancy, which we hope is not true, or s desperate need to change the contract to survive.  From the board room it is simply business.

Answer (score 108):

I block all ads, on all websites, without exceptions. Here is my feedback:

- All ads are spammy.
- All advertising networks are bad.
- All ads are low-quality.
- I don't care how carefully you vet them.
- Ads are not good content.
- If you have to sell ads to remain in business, your business model is, in the long-term, unsustainable, and you should be focusing your efforts on transitioning to a sustainable business model.

Comment: To hit on your last point - expansion is costly, and it will be for any website. Considering the sheer number of websites that SE runs (between meta sites and main sites), it's entirely acceptable that they need more revenue to be able to sustain.

Comment: For some StackOverflow sites, I don't think they're ever going to have a sustainable income model aside from ads, since they have a tiny audience with a very specific interest.  Most notably, the plethora of Area51 sites for various cryptocurrencies.  There is a lot of value in having Area51 as a means of providing new SO sites, but it's presently all cost and no revenue.  However, once some of those sites are established, better revenue models could be introduced.

Comment: I don't expect each StackExchange site to be independently financially sustainable. I mean the company as a whole needs a sustainable business model. Their current one isn't working, and selling ads on a few more sites is, at best, a stopgap measure.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler those tiny communities should be run on a donation-basis or just not run at all and let someone else figure out how to run that tiny community if SE can't figure out a better support model.

Comment: THIS ANSWER needs to be seared painfully into the eyeballs of EVERY business executive. I have a zero tolerance policy for spam, and site adverts are ALWAYS spam. If I go to the yellow pages to look for a plumber, the adverts on that site are perfectly reasonable; but if I'm reading an article, they are annoying spam. Period. If I could upvote this answer more than once, I would.

Comment: Add to that list the fact that ads are a primary incursion source for malware, which is my primary reason for using an ad-blocker.

Comment: I don't wholly agree. _Vetted_ and _non intrusive_ ads give sites like SE a way to not force everyone to pay to access. And as long as you stick with (somewhat I guess) reputable networks like AdSense, they vet their ads thoroughly so chance of malware is smaller (I personally usually use adblock btw)

Comment: However, a lot of sites don't use non intrusive ads or use crap ad providers so I use uBlock with great pleasure on those sites

Comment: This is the answer I came here to post, and I wish I could boldface the last bullet point in particular and then laser-etch it on every available surface at SE headquarters.

Comment: Using advertising as your primary revenue source is an unsustainable business model?  So, basically all of the internet, television, and radio are under an unsustainable business model?

Comment: @TTT Yes.  It's really that simple.

Comment: Agree that there aren't many income options for a site like SE other than Ads. Most subscription/patron based models depend on their heavy users supporting the site. But with SE the heavy users are contributors, and it does not make sense to ask people that provide your content to pay for that privilege. And it is much harder to convince occasional users to pay to use a site

Comment: @pavon: have you ever received reddit gold? I even got a platinum once. It's totally useless, but someone paid actual money for it.

Comment: @biziclop that's a very good point, actually. What if one could donate to good answers that helped them, and SE took a small cut (10% etc) from that?

Comment: I think there's only one site I've ever whitelisted the advertisements for. And there's. One. Very. Good. Reason. Why. Those advertisements are *from the site's own user base* without exception (heck, I bought an ad once myself). Or was, until a more recently. Those ads are still there, but they added a *single* banner ad served by Google. What'd I do? I blocked the one ad.

Comment: @zwol It's amazing then how many businesses have sustained themselves for decades or even more than a century with an "unsustainable business model." We must have very different definitions of what constitutes "unsustainable." (Granted, I would totally agree that a site that relies on _super-annoying_ ads like animated ones, clickbait crap ones, etc. are ultimately unsustainable, as you'll eventually lose your user base and/or they will ad block.)

Comment: @reirab File that under "the market can stay irrational longer than you can stay solvent." All of those businesses, without exception, would have been well-advised to find better revenue streams from eight o'clock, Day One; all of them are already taking actions against their customers' best interests for the sake of keeping themselves funded, and this will only continue to get worse until they go bankrupt or turn into spam farms. The process happens faster online but is inevitable regardless of medium.

Comment: @reirab The newspaper business, which indeed sustained itself for many decades, is imploding (has already imploded?) from loss of ad revenue. An absolute majority of ad revenue on the Internet goes to exactly two companies - Facebook and Google. Ad blocking is increasingly common, even on mobile. If you're not Facebook or Google, advertising is an unsustainable business model.

Answer (score 96):

Which sites is this experiment running on? As far as I've seen so far the exact list of site hasn't been documented officially.

I've said this before, but I really think that this kind of drastic change should be put on the relevant meta for each site that is part of the experiment (as long as it's a reasonably short list, otherwise it should be a globally featured meta post).

What does this mean for the principles SE has upheld previously for ads? The old standard was "excessively considerate, ludicrously on-topic", what has changed here? What kind of ad does SE consider inappropriate now? I've really no idea anymore on where SE draws the line for acceptable ads. This is probably the biggest damage this experiment has caused so far, it thoroughly confused the SE policy on ads.

What exactly are you testing for? Six months is really not a test in my view, this is close to establishing a new status quo for ads on SE. What parameters is SE observing here and using to decide on whether to go forward with the ads permanently?

Comment: The experiment will run on all SE sites in some shape or form during the 6 months. I won't post on each site about it, this announcement is sufficient. Inappropriate ads are full screen takeovers, punch the monkey, scam, pornographic, racist, etc. Some divergence from topic is ok but we'll monitor for exaggerations. Testing is for us to get an understanding of the quality of ad networks, profitability of the network, variety of availabilities, and other things as they come up. We're planning a recap of our findings at the end of the time period Stay tuned for that.

Comment: This already has been posted about on per-site metas for some sites. I'm just glad I am no longer seeing [ads for Stack Overflow for Teams](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5111/3221), which was entirely inappropriate for the site given the subject matter. Though now I'm not seeing any ads at all...

Comment: @JuanM Can we gather from this that, in a departure from existing ad policy, animations of any kind (including resource intensive, long loading and/or highly distracting ones) are *not* considered "inappropriate" as long as they stay within their 300x250 box? Or is there any whatever-natured threshold to animation that you can give the potential reporters guidance on?

Comment: @ChristianRau We're removing and stopping resource intensive, long loading, and highly distracting animated ads as soon as we see them.  It's not just about the dimensions of the ad, it's also the peripherals around it that matter.

Comment: @JuanM Some ads are resource-heavy for older computers or browsers without JIT. Pretty much any animated ad which isn't a GIF or APNG will max out the CPU on such systems.

Comment: @forest Noted and reported.

Comment: I'd like to see more "punch the turkey" ads. https://bytecode77.com/resources/sites/garage/software/super-turbo-turkey-puncher-3/

Answer (score 92):

For several days I've noticed that all "community ads" have disappeared, and intermittent "team" ads (irrelevant to the site) popped up for at least a day.  The particular site is tex.stackexchange.

The community worked pretty hard to craft ads to call attention to non-stackexchange resources that would be useful to newbies first visiting the site -- resources that provide more general information and facilities than can easily be conveyed in a question/answer format.  But these are now gone.

Will they come back?

---

**Update**

This was a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and has since been fixed. Thanks for pointing it out!

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

**Update by OP**

As of right now (a day and a half after the report that the bug was fixed), I see both ads for teams and paid ads (for a Microsoft product no less), but no community ads.  So something was *changed*, but not the fix that was requested.  Please take another look.

---

**Update**

This is fixed and community ads are appearing (not on every single page, but that's the same as it always was). We've shifted them down one slot if a paid ad appears on page.

[image: Tex community ad]

**Yet another OP update**

It has now been a week since the last acknowledged update.  And I have noticed an update in the interim that changed the appearance of the row of boxes that identifies the type of answer (probably to work better on a small screen, and probably effective for that).  But the ad situation has not improved.  They now seem to appear on fewer than 10% of pages, and team ads are much more frequent than community ads.  Unless my memory is greatly deficient, before this change, the community ads used to appear on far more than 50% of pages, and were relevant in context.  This is a very sad loss for our community.

Comment: @AlizaBerger -- How long before the fix is installed?  I'm still seeing intermittent "team" ads, and none for the community.  (I know that just a few hours isn't enough, so when should I check back?)

Comment: @AlizaBerger -- The "team" ads have now disappeared, but I still see no community ads. Granted they didn't use to appear on *all* pages, but they were much more frequent than absent.  Now there are (still) none.  I'll keep checking back.

Comment: Can you check a few questions that are answered? That's where I see them most consistently, and I *do* see them on TeX. I see one here, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497356/are-all-commands-with-an-optional-argument-fragile

Comment: @Catija -- Yes, there is an ad on that page, but it is **not** a community ad.  It's for Microsoft Azure, which has *nothing* to do with (La)TeX.  You can see all this year's community-approved ads here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8048 I haven't seen any of them on a tex.stackexchange page for more than a week.  These community ads provide links to TeX-related tools, other forums, and the user groups and meetings around the world.  All non-commercial.

Comment: Go [to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/768/how-do-i-convert-open-office-documents-into-latex) @barbarabeeton - hit refresh a few times if you need to; I get a community ad *every single time* there, across two browsers and three different accounts, even logged out.

Comment: @Shog9 -- The community ads are indeed appearing, at least for the cited question.  In fact, if I refresh the page a few times (after a brief delay), the ad changes.  Yes, that's what is wanted, although I wouldn't mind (and I think other members of the community wouldn't mind either) if these ads also appeared on unanswered questions.  Thanks.

Comment: @Shog9 -- Urk.  Still getting Microsoft Azure and team ads on the home page for tex.stackexchange.  Will this continue forever?

Answer (score 79):

Thanks for putting this on Meta so we can condense a lot of the information here.

#### I'm wondering if we're going to see ads tailored to particular sites in the future.

I'm as glad as anyone that [we can keep Joel caffeinated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287242/274942), and since the 2016 announcement and [the 2018 update on the ads program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306737/274942), I was looking forward to this move a little, because there had been two major reassurances:

1. Ads would have a *very* strict, excessively ludicrous quality control barrier, as Stack Overflow has stood by in the past.
2. Ads would be topical, if possible, for some or all sites.

Point 1 has been talked about recently by [a lot of people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329547/274942) and no doubt will see further discussion, so I won't kvetch about that. I'll talk about Point 2, i.e. topicality. There was a *lot* of emphasis a couple years on back on why network-wide ads would be beneficial for a lot of users; namely, that entire groups of non-programmers could be drawn in by ads related to the topics they're hear to ask and answer questions about. To use Tim's continued example of Seasoned Advice, there's a whole bunch of cooks in that kitchen who might be interested in cutlery-related advertisements.

From what we've seen so far, there has been no tailoring of ad scope to each site. Arguably the opposite. [Seasoned Advice saw some stuff](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3563/67657) that doesn't look like a spatula (kudos to y'all for addressing that quickly, though). All the ads seem generic; moreover, I'm getting the impression that SE doesn't have *any* quality or scope control over what ads we see - besides dealing with problematic ads after the fact and perhaps having a word with the party responsible. Which would imply that it's not getting better from here.

So here's my question: **Are we ever going to see topical ads?** We've got over 170 sites - I've given up counting by now - and it would of course be absolutely absurd to expect you guys to somehow figure out a whole bunch of ludicrously on-topic ads for each one. I'd be amazed if you pulled that off. But at the same time . . . not all of those sites are exactly prime ad targets, as had been acknowledged a couple years earlier. Maybe it would be possible to tailor ad topics if only a smaller subset of sites saw ads (it's easier to filter ads for 20 sites rather than 170+, right)? But from what you're saying, *every site* will get these ads eventually, at least in this phase of things.

As Tim said back in 2018,

> However, *you're the experts on these topics* and we're very likely going to listen to you.
>
> . . .
>
> Ads aren't just an opportunity to sell stuff, they're an opportunity to really show people that we understand a given topic.

It kinda seems like that idea has been given up on, which is a bit disappointing, because I thought it could be an awesome way to forge connections with the network sites . . . but I'd like to know if it's truly the case that it won't be happening. Of course, if you don't know yet, that's also fine. But . . . this was one of the positive things I thought might come out of this, and I'm not seeing heads nor tails of it.

Comment: I love the way you presented this! Yes, our goal is to have on-topic advertisements everywhere. It makes no sense for us to advertise things that are unrelated. However, this is currently taking time and discovery with networks that can fulfill the requests we're making via the 100K+ page views we generate per second. It's tricky but it's the goal. We want relevant ads but sadly we're running into issues while finding the right partners. We are aggressively seeking and responding to reports of bad ads. We want to bring value all sides. No one on the ads team wants to hurt any SE site!

Comment: @JuanM Yeah, I figure it would take time - and I also figured that might be why the experiment is so long, trying to optimize for as many sites as you can under those conditions. Thanks for expanding on that.

Comment: You're welcome! I agree that the experiment is long but in reality we're dealing with a lot more than just a few sites and a handful of topics. We want to get it right and we'll continue to push towards that.

Comment: @Juan with the talented people who work for you wouldn't it just be easier to build your own ad tech and not have to rely on finding the right partners, which from my experience don't exist? If your goals are a combination of profit and community relevance you might not find a network that can provide this as their usual goals are profit, profit, profit, profit and profit.

Comment: @razethestray That would be a large venture to do effectively, as you would have to invest a lot of resources in courting the interest of businesses whose ads you would like to host. SO could probably branch off an entirely separate business to do this *if* it successfully took off in the first place. That's a huge risk to take on.

Comment: Alienating it's entire userbase is a greater risk I would say.

Comment: @JuanM -- You say "No one on the ads team wants to hurt any SE site!"  But you *have* hurt at least one SE site by nearly completely removing the "community ads", which were crafted by the community to highlight non-SE sites that provide additional relevant information that is not suitably covered by a question/answer format.  We keep hoping they will return, but it seems hopeless.

Answer (score 77):

As a point for historic reference, you may want to consider the Spanish Fork, when the Spanish-language Wikipedia contributors left for a forked version of the project when Wikipedia announced it would consider running ads.  It is why Wikipedia still does not run ads, puts more focus on its nonprofit status, and has so much focus on fundraising by donations instead.

(Searching for stories to link to for more information, I found [this one](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/wikipedia-spanish-fork) and vaugely recall that the story might also be in [this chapter](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/open-sources-20/0596008023/ch20.html#opensources2-CHP-20-SECT-5) of a book that is not handy for me at present.)

Even if a sufficiently critical mass of regular contributors to SE got so upset by ads that they chose to fork and leave, such a group would still face challenges of funding server bills, development costs, non-community moderation (DMCA etc.), and face an uphill battle for visibility.  However, such a community might choose to manage the finances with [greater transparency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network/329770#comment1075792_329763) and orientation towards the good of the community instead of optimizing for shareholder value.  The existing SE could get closer to that if it chose to do so.

It seems that lately, we've seen an increasing level of the SE team getting away from user-centered design and listening to the community (just one example [here](https://medium.com/@cellio/dear-stack-overflow-we-need-to-talk-13bf3f90204f)), and this ads initiative with all its flaws and lack of basic considerations (esp. around site appropriateness!) is the latest in that pattern.

---

As part of this "experiment," we the community members have repeatedly heard false assurances about what will and won't be allowed.  For example, in a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/) about earlier ads on SO, Sr. Ad Ops Manager [Steve Feldman](https://stackexchange.com/users/1246026/stevvve) stated (emphasis original):

> We entered into an agreement with Stack Overflow users long ago that we wouldn’t subject them to low-quality ads. ...anything that doesn’t speak specifically to the Stack Overflow audience is not permitted. We also don’t accept rich media like animated ads, expandable ads, or video, which are the norm for most publishers today. This strict policy means we leave money on the table, but our team wants to protect Stack Overflow from those kinds of ads, as they run the risk of alienating that established trust. ...That focus on relevance and performance arrives early in the QA process. Whether it’s our sales people explaining that ads must have borders, or our campaign managers checking landing pages to ensure they adequately inform, *we are thorough.* ...Every single ad to appear on any of our sites is vetted by the operations team. *We check copy and content on the ads as well as the landing pages.*

In a [report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387186/798371) around animated ads being allowed in practice, readers learned   that SE is *not* "thorough" and does *not* vet "every single ad." As [explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387186/are-animated-ads-on-so-questions-accepted?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment712095_387222) by an ad teams member,

> We do a manual check of all creatives before campaign launch. Both when we receive the ad tag, and when we launch the campaign. What typically happens when one gets through, is that an agency updates their ad tags after we've launched the campaign.

As [noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387186/are-animated-ads-on-so-questions-accepted?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment712260_387222) following that explanation, there are automated ways to tell if something is animated or not. There are image formats that don't support animation, to which ads could be automatically restricted. If manual review of any new content is required, it's demonstrably possible and part of the system; changed content should be considered new content for this review's purposes.  The same review process should apply. If an advertiser has 10 different creatives they want to test in and out, then all 10 should be reviewed and approved, with the approved hashes stored. If there is a required review step, only approved images should be allowed. Advertisers should be allowed to substitute approved images for other approved images mid-campaign as much as they want, but why even require an approval process if it's not reviewing the less appropriate content that will actually be shown?

It's clear that advertisers **are** circumventing review to serve up ads not appropriate for this site, including animated ads and [script-running ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386487/798371) for browser fingerprinting (or, perhaps, whatever other malicious scripts an advertiser wants to run; trust is completely gone on this point).  SE's [response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386499/798371) is to not turn off those ads or even restrict ads to static images, even temporarily for however many weeks (minimum/already passed) or months/years it might take to implement a more complex solution, without clarity about why the added complexity is needed.

We also apparently can't have an [easy way to flag inappropriate ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329700/287315), which further shows the truth behind any nice words about how SE might say it wants to listen to members of the community or fix what's broken about the premature rollout of the SE-wide ads system.

---

Maybe there is a sense that the ongoing contributions of the community are less important than they once were as a result of SE having already built up such a large database of useful content; this site or any mirror would continue holding significant value even if all new contributions stopped tomorrow.   However, I caution against getting too comfortable in that position, and driving away contributions that are still core to the long-term success of SE's business model.

Comment: I would actually go as far as saying "lack of basic considerations (esp. around appropriateness!)". Some of the ads we saw aren't appropriate for **any** site in the network.

Answer (score 77):

> We've received reports ... We've also received reports ...

This is a big problem. Start taking some responsibility of the content posted on your site, *before* it goes onto the site. As a publisher, you are already legally responsible for it, so it will actually be in your own best interest to spend a minimum of effort into reviewing advertisements.

Comment: Agreed. Porn or scam ads are unacceptable and "we're just testing" is NOT an excuse. I already lost any trust in SE when it comes to ads, and nothing will bring that trust back, but hope they'll get better for the sake of other people.

Answer (score 73):

I don't have a problem with ads in general. But I see that animated ads are being allowed. Animated elements of any kind make the web cognitively inaccessible for people with visual processing difficulties. Specifically, it violates [WCAG success criterion 2.2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html) by including auto-moving elements that can't be paused by the user.

What happened to your [stated commitment to preserving accessibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307238/364707)?

Comment: It probably isn't profitable enough, a factor which tends to cause for-profit companies to drop prior commitments, especially without [strong incentives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329840/287315).  Even if they are holding to the [WCAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines), can you find/cite more specifically which part would prohibit animated ads?  I agree they're a bad idea, but a more specific citation in WCAG would help if making the accessibility argument about why.

Comment: @WBT It's 2.2.2. I've updated the post, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks; that makes it a much stronger post.

Answer (score 70):

I am concerned based on the examples cited by [Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329775/186281) and [HDE 226868](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329770/186281) and what they've already seen on the network.

These examples - Bikini ads on Workplace and foreign language ads on Seasoned Advice - seem rather low quality. Frankly, they sound like something that should have been caught before going live.

Can you explain a little bit about how the quality / search for advertising partners / process of getting ads to appear is different from what currently exists? Perhaps that will help us understand a bit more of *why* these types ads are appearing when many of us are accustomed to higher quality ads (or fewer ads due to privilege level).

Comment: I only know of their current system, from what I've read around: advertisers send SE the ads in a way, SE staff review and upload it to the place serving ads. Obviously, that's no longer true with the new ads. I'm almost sure they just let those who pay decide what to show, and can ask them to remove specific ads **only after they're being reported**. Will glad to stand corrected, but afraid I won't be.

Comment: (It was actually a lingerie ad that I saw on Workplace.  Somebody else reported seeing bra ads; not sure if that was Workplace or SciFi.  My bikini example was an extrapolation -- that could plausibly be relevant on a site like Travel, unlike the others.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio bra on Workplace (not the one who reported but saw that one myself as well)

Comment: Yeah, that's not good. These have been reported.

Comment: hmm, bikinis could well be appropriate on the workplace. For some people they're proper attire for their job after all. Think professional swimmers :)

Answer (score 69):

> If you wish to report an advertisement, please take a screenshot of the ad and paste the URL (if possible) along with the site where you saw it to a comment or answer. I'll report it to the ads team and we can track it down to investigate.

Were any engineers involved in the discussion about how to report ads?

Why don't you have a proper "Report This Ad" button that captures all of that info?

Comment: *Why don't you have a proper "Report This Ad" button that captures all of that info?* Probably because that would cost money to develop and run (i.e. do the investigations etc.), which would eat into the profits of running the advertising.

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329700/162102

Comment: @WBT: Yep, better to get us to do it instead for free. Like we do everything else... for free.

Answer (score 69):

Everyone keeps talking about animated ads and video ads, but I haven't seen any mention yet of a far more important topic: JavaScript in ads.

Simply put, there is no legitimate reason for it to exist, but plenty of illegitimate ones. [We've already seen malvertising showing up on Stack Exchange ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386487/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio). So far, it's been limited to browser fingerprinting, but it can easily get worse if that much is getting through.

We need a zero tolerance policy on ads running scripts.  The only acceptable standard is **no JavaScript code on any ad, on any site, for any reason, no exceptions, no excuses.** Anything less than this will get the site adblocked by a whole lot of tech-savvy users who want to protect their systems from malware.

Comment: to be fair, apparently it has NOT been limited to fingerprinting. Like I said in my answer, there are reports of ads that attempted to download actual malware, but I couldn't gather any more precise info. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/151?m=50759674#50759674) for one of such claims.

Comment: Oh hey, first downvote on this answer.  There must be a sleazy advertiser reading this...

Comment: no javascript is probably a non starter for SE. They're not rolling their own ad network, and all ad networks out there, especially google (the one they've chosen) require fingerprinting, tracking and full javascript enabled features for their partners.

Comment: You'd love uMatrix ... allows you to block scripts depending on where they're from, a bit long to set up, but really efficient once it's done.

Comment: @Magisch Too bad.  If Google doesn't care enough to filter things actively enough to keep malware out of their advertising--and they don't--then we don't care enough about their "requirements" to let them put security holes (such as JavaScript) in their advertising that people who want to stick us with malware can exploit.  As we say on the Internet, "this is why you can't have nice things."

Answer (score 64):

#### I am more worried about the next move.

OK, you have realized that your current buziness model is not so efficient and you need ads to make the sites running. I am not an expert and I should leave the technical complaints to the more qualified people. Some may even feel sympathetic and support this decision. Personally, I'll use my precious ad-blocker whenever I get annoyed and if the ad-blocker is out of hand (like when I'm on mobile) then I'll just curse. No problem.

But I'm imagining the situation that this model has a poor outcome, i.e. the ads get very few clicks due to the fact that most people are not interested in seeing them and block them. Then what would be the next move? May we get the message "**please turn off your ad-blocker, or else you won't be able to see the content**" whenever we visit the site? That is when the things get really ugly.

Comment: On sites that have ads already running, they also have ["reduce ads" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) with this statement (emphasis mine): "*We want to emphasize that you should only re-enable banner ads if you want to see them, **not because you're trying to support us financially**. In fact, it doesn't really do us any good to show you ads for products that you don't want to engage with.*" I'd sincerely hope they don't change that policy.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Actually I don't mind ads as long as they are relatively small and **not animated**. But unfortunately, most advertisers think that is the whole point of the ads! So they make them to be as annoying as possible. And if you are going to make money by showing ads, you have to bend by their rules.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT.  However, reduced ad privileges don't exist right now for the network and changing that is not a top priority for development effort, though [another answer here emphasizes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329812/287315) it should be (& I agree).

Comment: @WBT I kind of believe the privilege will be enabled when the testing is done (i.e. ads run officially). AFAIK, they deliberately turn off the privilege for the experiment to get more feedback on the ads.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Your optimism seems inexperienced.

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ if it comes to that, please remember that the content was originally licensed under the Creative Commons license. That means that you are allowed to republish it (with attribution) on some other site that won't hide it behind a wall of any sort. I hope we won't have to come to *that*, but it is still an option if things get really ugly.

Answer (score 61):

> Generating revenue from non-technology sites will enable us to dedicate more resources to meeting your needs so this is good news!

[image: "Good news, everyone!"]

I'd like to hear more about this "[good news](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRCzEqkCoiM)". The response from Stack Exchange staff on the Photography site (see [What can Stack Exchange do improve this site to better build a photography community of practice here?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/what-can-stack-exchange-do-improve-this-site-to-better-build-a-photography-commu)) has been *quite underwhelming*, with a lot of glib "this will enable the community" comments and clearly no reading at all of the existing community conversations even when I provided links to them.

Are there any active plans for helping sites like Photography reach their potential? To be completely honest, this feels like an afterthought to monetization (and therefore, the claim of "good news" a little... doublespeaky).

[image: actual "good news"?]

Answer (score 58):

#### At least allow the current reduced ads privileges to continue operating

The people who generate the content that generates ad revenue shouldn't be subject to the same level of ads.

#### Don't block adblock users

I know I personally will delete my account if that becomes a thing (especially if uBlock even can't get around it :-) ). Glaring at you APKMirror. I'm primarily on mobile data so every MB an ad uses in addition to the site counts. Though if you don't implement anti-adblock and make double sure nothing shady or any viruses get in ads, I'll disable it. These sites have helped me so much sometimes it's worth it.

#### I'll reiterate what others have said: nothing intrusive like animated or video ads

This is key to ensure users can also focus on the content and not just the ads. Also some users who maybe have seizures or likewise will appreciate that.

#### I can't say it enough. Content. Moderation.

You won't let me post pictures of women scantily clad or of shady Asian dating sites or posts with malware, so why should advertising providers be allowed to even if they provide money? A way to mitigate risk of malicious ads is to forbid JS in ads. Also try to focus ads to the site subject matter.

Also please include a way for us to flag inappropriate ads. We know your moderation systems can't always catch everything.

#### And offer removal of ads for a small monthly fee

And I mean *small*. Like single digits USD. Take a look at XDA ad-free for an example

**I'll be happy to discuss any  disagreement in the comments.**

Comment: *You won't let me post pictures of women scantily clad or of shady Asian dating sites or posts with malware, why should advertising providers be allowed to?*  Practical answer: because they are paying to post that.  Due to a deficit in choice of metrics and SE being a for-profit business, contribution of **funds** is what counts as valuable in the eyes of the company, not contribution of **content**.

Comment: @WBT That's not quite true. You can't just make a website full of ads and rake in the money. You need some mechanism to get people to actually look at the ads and possibly click on them. That's what the content is for.

Comment: @nwp and they *have* plenty of content, collected over the prior several years. See [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329840/287315) for some additional discussion.  I think they are being a little short-sighted in their decisions about what to recognize as valuable here.

Comment: _"And offer removal of ads for a small monthly fee"_ No, don't. This is a huge slippery slope.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not really. People may use adblock anyway and it'd give them a way to support SE without them forcing people to disable it

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife In terms of business decisions, it's one step away from a two-tier access model.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which they could enforce for ad-blocker folks, anyway.  At least this gives people a choice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does not have to be. Just think about how many people would donate (I do not say pay here). This could be sustainable, if SO just wants to do their job without too many experiments and side projects. And maybe it could even finance some side projects, because there are *a lot* of users and many users that could afford to pay a little bit.

Comment: @alloo And there are a lot who can't. Presto, you have a two-tier access model. The poor suffer, the rich don't. Nice!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would not propose _any_ sort of advantage like rep or privileges (besides maybe a badge by your username) given to those who pay to remove advertising. Two tier access only matters if paying gives you some sort of advantage over non paying users

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife The advantage is in being able to use the site without advertisements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but I fail to see how that's going to give a user an edge in anything. Not going to raise their rep or privileges.

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife This page is chock full of people saying that the experience without advertisements is better than the experience with them. Not sure how else I can put it, or why you're focusing on _competitive_ advantages that nobody mentioned

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my point is that I see no issue as long as it doesn't give you a competitive edge. Also **of course** I'd prefer no ads but _they have to pay the bills_ and some of us would happily support SE but have no desire to turn off our adblock, so a donation of some sort is logical. That also gives users a _reason_ to donate so maybe more will use it

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife Spoken like someone of privilege who would not be noticeable affected by the two-tier system :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually I use both hosts blocking and uBlock so I don't see ads or pay to remove them. As I said, paying to remove ads wouldn't give you any sort of advantage besides you may have a more pleasant visual experience on the site

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife Even more privileged! You can get the benefit without paying the cost. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm afraid I don't see how that's "privileged".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and a couple apps/sites I do pay to remove ads or whatever because _I value them_. Just I won't pay a site I visited twice ;-)

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife Now imagine you have no money.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit easily done. I'm making $9/hr and going to college

Comment: @TTT Trust me, considering that all the content - and that includes your own content - is licensed under the Creative Commons license... an armament race against the "evil adsblockers users that don't want our malware/scam/nsfw ads" isn't a fight SE can hope to win.

Answer (score 44):

The **value** in Stack Exchange, is its *contributors*. So Stack Exchange seeks to punish its contributors with ads? How is this a "good thing"? How is this the *best* way to generate revenue?

Comment: I mentioned it in another comment; they should just ask for donations and do fundraising drives like Wikipedia does. Seems to work for them and doesn't mess up the site with ads.

Comment: While not explicitly stated, I believe the [reduced ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) for users with 200+ rep will apply.

Comment: @RudolfOlah [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329840/287315) goes into more detail on the Wikipedia analogy.
I'm not a fan of this new answer because it doesn't really answer the question or add anything that the prior 24 answers didn't already cover.

Comment: @LShaver It *is* explicitly stated that "reduced ad privileges don't exist right now for the network" - that's only on certain sites.  Developing it out does not seem to be a priority.

Comment: As I *attempted* to allude in my statement. The (expert/quality) *answers* are the largest value. Why not leverage *that*? IOW why are those of whom provide quality replies to questions raised on StackExchange *punished* for doing so?

Comment: The difference is that Wikipedia started as and still is a non-profit, while Stack Exchange (at least in recent years) has always been concerned about investors and making money while not scaring away too many actual contributors.

Comment: There was quite a debate on Wikipedias protocol/polic(y|ies). Many feeling that it was just-plain-wrong for Wikipedia to profit so well off the backs of it's contributors. I won't cite anything here, because it 1) it may *skew* objectivity, and 2) this area is for comments. In any case other' *chosen* model(s) are *not* the only models available. Maybe StackExchange could use a *unique* model. Maybe poll it's users/contributors for thoughts on the matter in a Post(ing)/Poll of it's own?

Comment: I also resent being charged with the duty of "AD police". Why aren't the ADs being screened in advance? Why are *we* charged with the responsibility?

Comment: Sounds like they need to take this decision over to ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 38):

I haven't seen anyone bring the following up:

> Please do not have ads on beta sites.

These have enough problems as it is getting a community going. Until a site is graduated, it should be spared (non-community) ads.

Answer (score 37):

I don't think monetization on its own is bad. You need to keep the servers running, and the employees paid and happy. But I will echo some sentiment on the part of others here; if you think "Reactive" is good enough, you're wrong.

It might be one strike or three for some users. I run [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin), most of the sites I visit are white listed; if I enjoy their content they get my ad views. However, when those ads become malicious or obnoxious those sites lose that white list status... and they stay there. Several large sites are on that list for a fairly lax approach to dealing with the issue.

So sure be "reactive" in your experiment; but bear in mind that a lot of users will be running their own experiment. Transparency can only help your case, but if we never learn about ad-partners that you no longer work with, or reasons for slips in the ad quality, we have no incentive to turn ads back on.

Comment: I love this answer and how it simply explain one of the central points here. Stack Exchange may be doing its experiment to see which provider is trustworthy, but at the same time the user are performing their own. Sorry, but being "reactive" to bad advertisements flags when it is **MY** machine that is risking to get infected.... is just a big no on my book.

Answer (score 35):

Please avoid using animated ads and video ads.

They kill my cell phone's battery, as well as being annoying.

Comment: This answer has been given several times at least. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329960/223820), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329965/223820) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329951/223820). And with 324 upvotes, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329818/223820)

Comment: It cannot be said enough.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Yet here on SE, we are not a fan of duplicate answers.

Comment: None of the linked answers have mentioned device battery drain so I don't consider this a duplicate.  Most websites have transitioned to > 50% mobile traffic, so it's a real concern.  "XYZ kills my battery" is shorthand for "developer doesn't at least performance test their code."  Whatever happened to counting clock cycles?

Comment: @CubicleSoft in the age of smartphones, and ever increasing Internet access, more and more people are using their phones to watch movies and videos online than ever before. Can an animated ad drain battery as much as surfing on the Internet, e.g visiting Stack Exchange, and/or watching a video? Is cell battery life as big a concern as it was maybe five years ago? I'm not saying that animated ads don't have any ill-effects, I'm just wondering how often it has happened to SE users that their cells died (*they kill my cell phone's battery*) because of this.

Comment: @Mari-LouA An animated ad triggers a repaint which results in executing additional code, which means more CPU/GPU time.  So, yes, it will drain battery faster than a site that is completely static.  If the ad is Javascript-based, any changes to the DOM trigger UI changes.  If the ad is a video, it utilizes very CPU-intensive video decoding libraries and hit the GPU pretty hard.  Also, most network ads include telemetry code, so they are regularly initiating additional network requests long after the page is done loading.  I just had two Li-ion batteries inflate after 19 months of low use...

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Animated ads have a noticeable effect of my battery life. Your comment "...in the age of..." amounts to telling me I should buy a phone with a bigger battery. That's an arrogant attitude on your part, and you should think about whether you've the right to tell people how to run their lives.

Answer (score 26):

I wouldn't mind (non-animated static picture) ads at all.

But I don't like **tracking**. That's why I use [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin). It's not to block the ads themselves; it's to block Google or whoever from following me everywhere I go.

Perhaps you could sell your own ad space directly instead of outsourcing it to a third-party network? Stack Overflow is big enough you could probably sustain it, and it might even make more money by cutting out Google. Not to mention people like me who block the ads not because they're annoying, but because Google is running them - I would probably whitelist Stack Exchange in that case.

Answer (score 23):

## Please consider rethinking your strategy.

There seems to be a push for monetization currently going on at Stack Exchange.
A few examples of this:

1. stackoverflow.com leading to a sales page for unauthenticated users.
2. The countless UI changes and call to actions aimed at peddling Stack Overflow Teams.
3. Stack Overflow Jobs.
4. And now this.

It's gotten to a point where even some moderators are weighing in against these moves.

I think it's time for Stack Exchange to come out and clearly state what it wants to be. Do you want to be a services company or a community?

Wikipedia had to make such a decision regarding this topic, and they opted to hold donation drives instead, which is consistent with their commitment to fostering their community.

I think that, similarly, Stack Exchange has to face such a decision. It would be the honest thing to do, since right now it's staying on the fence and is not sure whether it wants to milk the community or invest in it by providing better moderation tools, etc.

**Baiting and Switching**

Lastly, I would like to comment on how this move looks like to a mere user like me:

To me, this feels like a bait and switch, similar to what other tech companies are doing as of lately.

All these companies are luring you in with a "community feeling" or "free" stuff, enticing you to spend countless hours of your free time contributing to their product, oftentimes with some numbers, badges or virtual medals as a reward.

All that is perfectly fine. However, it turns out that corporate has not revealed their full plan. See, when the userbase is well established and sizable, their plan is to come in and monetize everything, even if users are against it. Yes, feedback might change a minor thing or two, but the eternal quest will always be: How can we make even more money off our users?

This thread is a perfect example of this, as execs ponder whether to serve ads with JavaScript tracking and animated ads to volunteers that are basically the lifeblood of the site.

I think Stack Overflow will benefit from some introspection, to hopefully choose a different path.

Comment: Re *"when the userbase is well established and sizable, their plan is to come in and monetize everything, even if users are against it"*: An example is [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)).

Comment: I like this answer.  However, "How can we make even more money off our users" is just one way to interpret the push for money.  The other possibility is "How can we make enough to keep the lights on."

Comment: The wikipedia model is untenable for stack. stack is a for profit company owned by shareholders, and as such has a fiduciary duty to maximize returns for said shareholders. wikimedia is a non profit org that has a fundamentally (and legally) different focus.

Comment: @Magisch I think the main takeaway from this post is that Stack Exchange needs to decide/say if it wants to be a "services company" or stay community focused. If it came forward with a decision, you wouldn't get this kind of community pushback, because the community would know what to expect and if they want to continue using the service or not.

Comment: @WayneConrad I think the push here is not to merely "keep the lights on". I can hardly envision Stack Exchange execs saying "To keep the lights on, let's test some animated ads and perhaps open up to third party publishers that will push ads with js tracking code to our unpaid volunteers". I definitely think that the hypothesis of shareholders trying to maximize profit makes more sense in this context.

Comment: @FranciscoH. it's always been a services company, being a vc funded for-profit enterprise. The community aspect of it is startup that you see from other companies in other industries similarly, you generate user interest and engagement first and only when you get a sizeable market share you start turning the profit valves. This isn't a new model and was always to be expected.

Comment: "Do you want to be a services company or a community?"  Umm... you do realize this is SO, right?  It's been actively, openly hostile to the idea of creating a community for years now.  The sort of interpersonal interactions that lead to community formation are deemed "off-topic," closed, downvoted, and deleted with a vengeance.  This comes directly from the top, with [ideas like this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-group-is-its-own-worst-enemy/) treated as gospel.

Answer (score 22):

In order to display ads on my computer (i.e. be whitelisted in [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin)) you must adhere to minimum standards for ads.

1. No animation/video
2. No cookies
3. No JavaScript code
4. No tracking/ping backs
5. No slowing down page loads
6. No more than 10% of the screen space
7. "Report ad" button next to each one
8. No [NSFW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NSFW#Adjective) content
9. Guarantee that any damage caused by your site (e.g. malvertising) will be rectified, i.e. paid for

These terms are fairly easy to comply with, the simplest option being to simply serve up human-reviewed JPEG files from your own servers.

Comment: Nice list :-) However: (4) is impossible, because the ads are coming from external sources. (5) is impossible, all extra functionality makes the site at least a little bit slower. But it would be possible as *"no significant slowing down on most common computers"*. (7) is a google feature, the OP does not mention the google specifically (they could use any other ad services as well). Furthermore, I had exactly zero effect by reporting all the m$ spam hours long. (9) is impossible, no company would ever rectify anything what happens independently from it.

Comment: Btw, imho you are still very fair with this list - I think, the typical behavior of most adblocker users that they simply block all ads, everywhere, without any feedback or discussion.

Comment: For 4 and 5 the solution is to serve small image files from the same server as the rest of the content. Most slowdown is due to needing to look up and contact external servers, that then run an auction before returning the data. Using a local server also means no advertiser tracking.

Comment: Oh yes, it would be nice :-) The problem is that SE commits all reasonable to do so many by external providers as possible. Even their javascripts are coming mostly from remote services, even the images are hosted by the imgur.com .

Comment: @peterh I'm not aware of major problems with imgur, and in my opinion, imgur does a great job hosting images for SE. That is a sustaintable partnership and imgur was carefully choosen due to their excellence, stability and reliability. Also, hosting elsewhere in some very stable place pieces of javascript needed for major functionalities and developed by in-house developers with great care is also something really good. That is something veeeeeery different than allowing the execution of any random unknown snippet of javascript provided by someone else who nobody knows for certain who is.

Comment: @VictorStafusa It is true. But *anybody* external provider can track us, and in many cases, I simply can't see other option for them to make money (see, for example, imgur where you can upload unlimited pictures until the infinity).

Comment: Using a few well known JS and image hosts is okay. Chances are they are already looked up in the DNS cache and the JS is already cached too. It's the ad servers that are the problem. Not just slow, but easy to infect with malware too. Remember when the WSJ served up malware for a whole weekend?

Comment: @peterh you are right -most of those points are "impossible" with the common "modus operandi" companies have imposed over users in the last years. But since apparently malware isn't a company problem since it comes from external sources and therefore is only an end user problem if browsing their sites infect you with some virus due to malwertising.... I guess one could selfish say it is not *our* problem if working with unreliable external ads providers makes adhering to this list impossible.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist if the site operator does not want to accept responsibility for malvertising, there is no obligation (moral or otherwise) on the user to load those adverts.

Answer (score 19):

May I make a suggestion?  We should use feedback in our ads from the Coalition for better ads.

I think we should avoid these kinds of ads:
https://www.betterads.org/standards/

And use more these kinds of ads (in green):
https://www.betterads.org/research/

Comment: Can you summarise here? The links could become broken.

Comment: agreed, I'm worried stackoverflow are just straight up making dumb mistakes right now. I hope they improve - they have a reasonably good track record of ending up doing mostly reasonable things because of lots of people telling them to, but it's not always the case.

Answer (score 16):

### Guideline proposal

- Static advertisements: only a raster image (or vector inlined in a data URL to avoid code execution), with an `https` link openable on click, in `_blank` target and with an explicit warning.
- Upvote and downvote buttons for each ad, one of the major and most useful features of the network.
- Report button allowing to specify a message, avoiding irrational reports.
- Topic-targeted advertisements: each site on the network should show contents related to the site topic, without tracking the user in any way.
- Careful selection by a well-trained staff, with graphic design knowledges among other things.
- No animations, nor audio, nor video.
- Avoid technological revenges against advertisement-blocking users, simply display a small message in place of the add telling them that they will only see useful and relevant static advertisements that don't disturb nor track them. This change should be felt as an improvement to the community, not only as «another way more to make money».

---

### Way to go

Here we can add suggestions related to the management of the advertising network:

- Create your own advertisement network for Stack Exchange sites, offering a high-valuable target: humongous collection of intelligent people that are willing -not exactly, but sounds well- to see relevant advertisements in moderate to low amounts.

  ---

### Balance

#### Advantages:

- Stack Exchange increases the revenue needed to keep working, expand their services, and fulfill their gastronomical needs.
- The users can benefit of curated and purposeful advertisements.
- All we will benefit from the economical progress of Stack Exchange.

#### Disadvantages:

- Advertisements can clutter the clean user interface.
- Generalist advertisement networks can pose many threats to the user security and well-being: inappropriate content, code execution...

---

<sup>**Note:** This answer is intended to serve as a **constructive** community wiki resource so we can centralize our reaction without repeating ourselves. Instead of downvoting the original post to show our feelings, we can simply expand this answer and upvote it.</sup>

Comment: I think there is ***way*** too much meta information in this answer (why this answer exists, etc.) and that meta information is way too prominent. Can you move it off to comments or deemphasise it by moving it to the end (e.g. make a section at the end titled *"About this answer"*), putting it in parentheses, formatting (making it smaller by `sub` / `sup`), etc.?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I've done some minor changes to the wording and formatting in order to increase the solidity of the answer. Yes, it was too meta-meta.

Comment: Note: I'm not a native speaker and you must find more errors, but the URL lowercase variation was a conspicuous fault. What was I thinking?

Answer (score 14):

## List of the "topical ads".

### Somehow **NSFW**, and **Animated**

#### 1. 2019 09 16: On  SciFi.SE .

> [image]

#### 2. 2019 09 17: On Workplace.SE, and Travel.SE   .

> [image]

with animation here https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=Qz0vFA1iZriUIOLHhxqE

#### 3. 2019 09 18: On Workplace.SE, Academia.SE .

> [image]

with animation here https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=SqKf2HoBhvvuQTmWIPn4

#### 4. 2019 09 19: On Music.SE

> [image]

with animation here https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=Qz0vFA1iZriUIOLHhxqE

Comment: Oh, hadn't seen the Workplace one had been posted already, [reported it as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333536/398063). It's being tackled. Should it be removed from this answer? Were the other ones also taken care of?

Comment: @Jenayah, got the same answers 2 days ago -> https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/wriggleling-ads-on-sci-fi?noredirect=1#comment44150_12691 .

Comment: Oh, somehow hadn't made the connection

Answer (score 13):

My two cents.

1. No animated ads. If I see an animated ad on a site, I turn on my ad blocker; you lose.
2. I don't care which site I'm on, I'm still the same me. So this "targeted ads" thing means little to me. No matter if I'm on scifi.SE or on SO, an ad for the latest novel by GRRM has the same impact on me. Similarly, ads for coffee or beer only depend on whether I'm at work or at home, not which site I happen to be visiting.

You know me already, I have cookies enabled, my profile filled out, etc. So show me the ads I'm interested in, not the ads that would be appropriate to the URL I'm looking at. Thank you.

The rest I want to say has already been said, but better, in this thread, so I'll refrain from repeating all that.

Comment: Just had one Animated ads.

Answer (score 12):

All of the content on this entire network is provided by users, not by the owners of the website. You are talking about taking  content provided free of charge by site members; placing adverts upon it to annoy casual users and contributing members alike; and pocketing the money. That is, at the very least, unethical.

If you allow animated adverts and adverts completely unrelated to the subject matter, people will use adblockers in droves.

If you block people using adblockers, they will either work around your block, or leave.

I, for one, refuse point-blank to tolerate ads; especially animated ones.

Comment: "That is, at the very least, unethical." Probably depends on how many ads they place. If they would place only a few ads to cover the running costs I would consider it ethical. The more money they make for themselves, the more questionable it becomes. The real "good news" is that the content is free. At any point in time others or the community can continue without or maybe with less ads. We have competition around the free content.

Comment: @Trilarion _We have competition around the free content._ - do we? Who is the competition? Is anything comparable to SE?

Comment: @shiny-metal "Who is the competition?" Sorry. I meant it more like, there could be competition. I don't think there is actually currently. There some sites copying content from StackOverflow and as long as they give attribution they are even completely legal. But that's it more or less, I think.

Comment: The content comes from users, but the servers, maintenance, and SEO that provides essential visibility come from SE.  It's not unethical for them to try to earn revenue from the sites.  Where ethics get more dicey is when the user contracts that have been in place for years (like the one about ad quality) start falling by the wayside.  It's still their network, but poor decisions can erode trust.  Users are free to take the content and set up elsewhere (per the license), but making that work is *not* trivial.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It depends on the balance I would say. Wikipedia also has servers, maintenance and SEO and they could show topical ads, but they don't. They probably could earn more from their site but nobody really likes ads. They distract the reader and lower the value of the presented content. The higher the profit for the owners of the network here, the lower the value for the users (and content creators). The right balance is okay, the wrong balance not. In the end, ads are a necessary evil not "good news" as Juan wrote. Let's just hope, the network keeps the balance.

Comment: @Trilarion Wikipedia also has an annual pledge drive and a non-profit corporation behind it (which reduces the taxes they pay).  I'm not saying that ads are the only answer; I'd prefer to avoid them too.  I'm just saying that it's a stretch to jump to the ethics claim you made.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It all depends on the actual extent. What I like about the Wikipedia approach is that it maximizes the value for the user. How much advertisement is okay and how much is too much - I guess that is up to debate and personal taste but just look at the score of this announcement, it's quite negative. People don't like ads. Facebook, StackExchange, Wikipedia - they all evolve around user generated content. Some are more evil, others more good. StackExchange is somewhere in the middle of them, I would say.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

The advertisement in between the post is hidden when the zoom size is increased more than 100%. But the advertisement in the side bar is not hidden for the 100%+ zoom. Also, when reduced the zoom size it is displaying the advertisement in between the post and the side bar.

As I aware Stack Exchange is not supporting other than 100% zoom. But displaying the advertisement based on the zoom size is looks like bug.

GIF for evidence:

[image: Zoom 100%+]

Comment: That's one way to block an ad.

Answer (score 9):

I'm rather on the fence with this one.

On one hand, at work I block all ads and trackers, no exceptions.  This is for security reasons as well as to prevent ridiculous unethical ads.  And I only use SO at work, so in essence I will never see the ads. (and if I do, I will manually block each one)

On the other, at home, I generally wouldn't mind ads, as long as they aren't distracting.  Same with cellphone apps and games.  I don't mind ads *as long as they aren't distracting*.  (I use adblock+ (default setings), and so non-distracting ads do show up from time to time, and I don't mind.)

I emphasize the distracting bit, because on a site with distracting ads, I either put it through Firefox Focus (removes all ads and trackers, clears cookies), or use reading view.

The bottom line here is *if you want ads to be effective, they have to be tailored to the specific site, and be opt-in*

I haven't clicked an ad (more than the number of fingers on one hand) in my entire internet career, except by accident because it was one of the annoying ones.  That's 20+ years of almost 24/7 internet.  But I sometimes later go to the store to buy whatever it was that was advertised if I really wanted it.  Advertisers must hate me.

Comment: "But I sometimes later go to the store to buy whatever it was that was advertised if I really wanted it. Advertisers must hate me."  Not really.  They got what they wanted (to alter your spending habits to buy their product) and and probably didn't even need to pay the website owner for the privilege, because you didn't click on the ad.  Ads aren't (usually) designed to get you to click them, they're designed to get you to remember the thing being advertised when you see it later (i.e. in a store) because there was an ad about it earlier.

Comment: To be fair, I wouldn't mind ads if they weren't **damaging**. Damage include visual damage (ie: too much visual distraction, flashing colors, screen occupation percentage etc), audio damage (autoplay audio), privacy damage (tryes to fingerprint your machine), malware damage (the ads tries to install malware on your system) and so on...

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to create some network-wide "reduced ads privilege" for your most active contributors.

Actually, I see your ads only rarely (if my adblocker needs some tuning). However, many of your worthy contributors won't do that. I suspect, you don't want to lose them.

Answer (score 8):

If you were to have ads, I would like them to be designed to the same look and feel of the Stack Exchange network. Ads are designed to pull our attention away from what we want to see.

Also to prevent these ad exchanges from buying the slot to resell.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about preventing ad exchanges from reselling the slots...that is primarily what they do!

Comment: Please don't. Quite the contrary: as much as you have influence on this, please make ads look different from the normal StackExchange design styles as much as possible. If the ad looks too similar to normal StackExchange content then that might trick my mental ad filter and then I'd see the ad.

Answer (score 8):

## I Support this Choice

I for one think it's time the site starts to mirror the appearance of other sites with equally useful information, like Buzzfeed and the Gawkster of yore.

They're not corporate overloads, they're concerned father figures looking out for our digital Fatherland.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### Option 2 - paid subscription

It's obvious that you need to earn money so that we can use this great network.

However, ads is only one side of the medal so I'd like to suggest an alternative for people who can stand them but still value the network.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I'd be happy if there was an alternative to ads as a **paid subscription plan** so that people who don't want to see that irrelevant spam just can pay for using the website and focus only on the content.

---

No matter how *friendly* ads are, they are always distracting.

I also agree with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329812/277922) answer that contributors should be spared from seeing ads.

#### Option 3 - dedicated ad pages

There is one more option but it might be a too outside-of-the-box one.

Build a dedicated page with only ads and put a link to it somewhere so that people feeling like seeing some ads can go there and focus only on that and let the rest of the content clean.

Comment: Option 3 is expressly forbidden by most ad providers. I've seen it myself with AdSense and a couple of other ones. Agreeing that you should be able to pay to remove ads

Comment: @INLOwnerInnonetlife wow, I didn't know that :-o this would be so much more efficient and people wouldn't hate ads so much. Maybe some day they will understand.

Comment: If StackExchange is getting desperate enough to test ads that aren't job ads or ads for their own products, at this point Option 4 is "ask for donations". The model is working well for Wikipedia?

Comment: @RudolfOlah I like the idea of Option 4, and I think there's a way they could encourage donations. They could add an icon next to the username of donors (similar to how the diamond goes next to moderators). Donors can opt in to show the amount of server time they've paid for on mouse-over of the icon. This will encourage people to show off how much they've invested in keeping the site funded to prevent ads, and that will in turn encourage others to donate as well.

Comment: Maybe even bronze, silver, and gold badges for recurring donations. Bronze badge would be "donated once", silver badge would be "annual donations", and gold badge would be "monthly donations".

Comment: @called2voyage this could be followed by some additional privileges... I like that donation idea too.

Comment: @shiny-metal I don't like the idea of basically paying for advanced privileges, but maybe it could give access to bonus features.

Comment: @called2voyage sure, the privileges should be _neutral_, statistics, seeing voting counts etc. There are many people who mostly read, have accounts, vote a lot but otherwise rarely contribute. They could be able to do simple extra stuff.

Comment: I'm voting up for option 2 (for users that don't achieve a reduced ads privilege). I would also like to block links to other SE sites (without resorting to an adblocker).

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing a high number of heavily animated ads now like the following:

https://s0.2mdn.net/8467101/1561981085980/AUD_Branding_072018_728_90_DC/index.html

There were some worse ones, but I didn't grab the link for them.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There is a Microsoft ad (Microsoft Azure) that causes strange behaviour on the browser back button. For a full report see: [Returning from question requires to go back twice, ad causing extra (identical) entry in history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387743/returning-from-question-requires-to-go-back-twice-ad-causing-extra-identical)

This ad is also present on other sites in the network, and causes similar behaviour there. See: [Microsoft Azure advertisement breaks the back button behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331755/microsoft-azure-advertisement-breaks-the-back-button-behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

**Please test the [ReadTheDocs advertising model](https://readthedocs.org/sustainability/advertising/)** too. (I've skimmed and searched all existing answers and didn't see this mentioned.)

As Mike Masnick writes, [targeted ads are probably useless](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20190319/23223441830/what-if-google-facebook-admitted-that-all-this-ad-targeting-really-doesnt-work-that-well.shtml) for most purposes. Or as the Ad Contrarian puts it, «For several years the [advertising industry has been engaged in a conspiracy](https://adcontrarian.blogspot.com/2019/09/a-conspiracy-of-silence.html) to deceive its clients and the public about online advertising».

Now, I understand that the whole point of testing generic ads is that the smaller sites don't have enough traffic to justify curation of site-specific topical ads, and at the same time their audience is sufficiently diverse that it's probably impossible to find any ad which is on topic for all of them. However, I argue this may not matter so much after all.

If some external statistics can be trusted at all, the stackexchange.com domain is much bigger than readthedocs.io, but maybe one order of magnitude bigger. It's not an entirely different planet in terms of traffic. What works there might work here too. You just need to convince advertisers that they don't need some hyper-targeted ad. If nobody is interested in buying all the traffic at once, as they seemingly do at ReadTheDocs, maybe you can slice it in a few pieces by geography or something. This isn't necessarily very hard: it's what every local news media has done for ages, and there's no evidence they were doing a worse job at marketing than what folks are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea if it puts food on the table. Just get the user feedbacks and implement this properly.

Comment: Well, [they are headed for an IPO of Stack Exchange (after a 10x in revenue/size)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s) - from 70 million USD to 700 million USD.

Answer (score -16):

YouTube offers its content creators a way to monetize their efforts - the ad revenue that the company earns is in part earned by content creators' efforts; and as such they get a fraction of ad revenue.

Have you considered that approach for ads displayed on the SE network?

- If you do so, you encourage quality content
- If you fail to do so, you actively demoralize and discourage content creators who made the sites work, by earning money off the backs of their efforts.

Comment: I don't think they will ever implement this idea. But if it is implemented then i'm sure that many people will start seeing SE network as a source of income like YT and it will eventually benefit the whole network.

Comment: @CodeIt ...and invite a ton of bullshit content with the sole intention to make money, not too much unlike YouTube. To battle this you have to find a way to make only the contributors who *deserve* it to gain profit and this in turn isn't particularly easy to measure. Use votes or views? Yeah, now people won't just post clickbait crap for HNQ rep but for money.

Comment: @ChristianRau You are absolutely right. That's why i wrote in the beginning that *i don't think they will ever implement this idea*.

Comment: @CodeIt It was the end of your comment that prompted my response, not the beginning of it, unless there was a word missing in that sentence.

Comment: @ChristianRau There are individual developers who are spending a lot of time in sites in SO to help fellow developers. I still think if SE is able to correctly implement this idea, it will eventually benefit those people.

Comment: @ChristianRau - that part is easy, there's TONS of great proposals to fix the BS effects of HNQ. SE simply doesn't care enough to fix them.

Comment: This isn't solely an HNQ problem, in fact the HNQs are entirely orthogonal to this. Once you bring in a monetary motivation, people will go out of their way to get the quick buck. While even now some people might get obsessed with reputation a little too much, wanting to make a quick buck by writing a few words on the internet is a whole 'nother level of wrong motivation.

Comment: "If you do so, you encourage quality content" Oh please, is there a site with worse quality of content than Youtube? I can't think of one. The monetizing is one of the main reasons why there's so much trash there.

Comment: @Lundin - not the channels I'm interested in (musicians, for most part). I see amazing performances for free, because they make money off ads. Most of the issues with Youtube are due to its algorithms not the fact of monetization

Comment: Quora has gone this route, and it's terrible.

Comment: @Lundin There is an *enourmouse* amount of *extremely* high quality content that wouldn't exist without YouTube providing money to creators.  The model just doesn't translate well to providing accurate and useful practical programming solutions the way it does to entertainment, and it's also such a stark contrast to the site's design and values that it wouldn't work here.  But in the field of entertainment media on a platform specifically constructed around the model of paying people for doing a good job of entertaining others, it's a great model.

Comment: +1 I think this is the way forward, users who consistently provide "great" answers should get a miniscule percentage of any generated revenue their answer appears on, I stress, a token, a penny dropped in the fountain, not a salary. Until their answer gets upvoted >1,000 in which case... reward the user with quality merchandise or swag?

Comment: But the answer is misplaced, it veers off to a different topic, specifically How does SE=SO generate revenue? Maybe you might want to consider posting here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329846/are-there-any-great-reasons-for-or-against-having-a-paid-for-tier-for-the-main-s?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - ... *\[citation needed\]*. The channels I'm exposed to mostly consist of musical performances.

Comment: Yet on SE we strive to *generally* uphold quality and optimize for pearls rather than sand. I'd much rather the *site* already optimizes for that (which it at least calims as their goal to do) rather than *me* having to do that. You picking yourself the pearls among all the crap YouTube has to offer is all well and good, but also largely incidental.

Comment: @Servy, if YouTube doesn't have the majority of the world's video content, it's not for lack of trying.  When you've got that much content, it's not surprising that you've got enormous amounts of extremely high quality content.  The problem with YouTube is the *density* of quality content: pick a video at random, and it's probably going to be a steaming pile.  SE, on the other hand, tries to optimize for density of quality content rather than raw numbers.

Comment: @Mark Sure.  YouTube's design is to not focus at all on a signal to noise ratio, and instead rely on having recommendation algorithms, and relying on quality content being shared on 3rd party sites, so that people only find the good content and simply never see much of the crap content on the site.  SE accomplishes the same thing with answered questions by relying on Google to serve the good content to people.  The problem SE has is that it needs questions to be answered, which means having experts sifting through all incoming questions looking for stuff to answer, hence why it needs curation.

Comment: I think your idea is good ( +1 ). The problem is that the SE business model is, converting internet points ("reputation") to physical money ($$$). It is unlikely that they would want to change it.

Answer (score -37):

Please block ad-blocker users, **but** allow them to pay for the service (costing no more than fixed subscription costs + average advertisement income) if they don't want to see advertisements. That way the rest of us won't see more ads to pay for their access to the SE services and you actually provide a solution for those who are unhappy to see advertisements in general (whether for valid privacy reasons or just because they don't like them).

The reason I am proposing that is just because it feels somewhat unfair that the focus here seems to be to earn more money from the users who are already earning you money, rather than focusing on the users who are currently using your services and not paying for it in any shape or form.

(And lastly: Please ensure that the default is a non-privacy infringing option where no user profiles will be built and no (user) targeted advertising will happen *by default*. If a user wants to opt-in for their personal data to be used for more relevant advertisements, then go them! That however should be an opt-in choice (luckily a lot of interpretations of GDPR require this, but the big ad networks are trying to slip through with a legitimate interest based argument))

Comment: I'm not paying SE for the little benefit I get from it, and I'm not exposing myself to the risk that Google Ads are. I guess I'll just stop answering altogether.

Comment: All the people who volunteer their time to keep the site clean will go home, too. The CV queue is overflowing as is.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Yeah, definitely makes sense, please also don't read the answers then  . Totally makes sense that not each service is valuable to each person. If it's not valuable to you then that's totally okay. And yes, I agree that active contributors should see less/no ads.

Comment: Without moderators, this site won't be valuable to any expert. Without experts, this site won't be valuable to homework dumpers either. Without the pillar of SO, the rest of the network won't hold either.

Comment: *Please block ad-blocker users, but allow them to pay for the service (costing no more than fixed subscription costs + average advertisement income) if they don't want to see advertisements.* How to wreck your entire community in less then 10 seconds. Contributors already pay for SE's bottom line with their time and energy.

Comment: @Magisch Maybe payment would be an option to get the "no-ad privilege" without being a worthy contributor ("worthy contributor" could be defined in this sense by some rep/badge/etc criteria). Worthy contributors would get the "no-ad privilege" automatically, without payment.

Comment: Some people only use adblockers for accessibility. Having to pay to make a site accessible places a burden on folks with disabilities.

Comment: ಠ_ಠ _Please block ad-blocker users, but allow them to pay for the service (costing no more than fixed subscription costs + average advertisement income) if they don't want to see advertisements._ - If I don't want to see advertisements I will not come to your website, simple as that.

Comment: If SE blocks ad-blockers, I'm deleting my accounts.

Comment: As he said so he did. R.I.P user474678