# Are beta stats removed from the home page?

Tags: bug, beta-sites

We are generally shown stats of beta sites on the right side of home page under watched and ignored tags. I am not able to see them now. In the place of beta stats, I am directly seeing Hot Network Questions under ignored tags. I checked while logging in and logging out.

Are they intentionally removed or is it a bug?

Comment: Might be related with the Ad testing. Some cheese moved in right bar.

Comment: [The ad testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763)?

Comment: No repro now. What sites you mean? Some sites still have the beta design but are not in beta phase anymore, e.g. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ShaWiz Yeah, they are back now. I think no repro. Even help us grow in the site was absent. But it is back. I was talking about sites like Interpersonal.SE  sports.SE etc,

Comment: Not no-repro. Fixed. Will explain in a few.

Comment: @Catija 14 hours later, guess you meant few days? No worry, no rush. :-)

Comment: @Catija Perhaps a tag edit indicating fixed bug?