# Non-tech ad on Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, advertising

I clicked on a [Stack Exchange ad](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F3402btE%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1gQbAnBljRMSE50T8XIpXyyxeZApVRqa-eDU768zPUSuMoJ4jYVe_OvHU&h=AT2NxGGoPrM3JbqmW2_XTAvfwkY0VVBZnAnyTqNlc1zpPNUf2V8xjNeq02bSYQ5StKUMVtc65BY5aZmVi0AlR0GATZ30UGnu-8Hb0VAoCoa57K6xUpzQFAhwbzgjToUMUX3cQwWm30CTw5fJS3yl-RnzoLJwc6RRdWBgIjAW7quAByU4L18oA4JulAlNU2-IDWoZAy3dPonl9OOwOxCVy9Qj5g6cL0S_oK814rxBGQqOElAk0yZPrqqtjS0ve5Ms2b0ApbveEKZVNK1idalXn24tRgOUYqr2H1LdkDWaR0yPh1bzCA9u21FrRjWozNi-s7yoPNFXao9W-XGZK5sEJ4ugufyff1pEPAhlfmHRWXtsTJY1AES7grM3XlTTix2EgnmQIUgGZ3AYT39b9SIjk8Q6o8OK0iPHiNO1x1ujbUVkMEglhd3Lwdeuh4ZFANWYQHcKrHPLeNrM-zfnVkJykufGn2Et7wJHNCkGJL6U8ZCg8UGSn1Nsklo95o181bQeDU_wOM3cliYRHPRZzMgcgJ4R8PmFSZQmVD6C2R5TZYPspwHh5dwkZ4oKdu0qB1r42y9jD7QRhs5V2lOM43skbTggr17UrKenjrLC6srWcMskpWZZ0eTpG8KcbLPgt4Xb0hZKA6hzjzlbChFsM8OuHP40mvg7zttM7ZRJ) on Facebook and saw this:

[image]

I have used SE for many years, and I have never seen such a non-tech add...
Is this something my ISP injected? Maybe Facebook did it? If so, is SE aware of this practice? It ruins the brand you (we) have built!

Comment: Sticker, peel, tears. That ad is pretty spot on ....

Comment: Possibly kind of related: [SE is testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763)

Comment: Though.... What is it an ad for? That looks badly cropped...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to confirm with the ads team that this was a brief test that was being conducted at that time.  The ad is no longer live.  Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into these matters.

Comment: What made SO/SE such a big success? It wasn't the gamification, it was how clean the site looked compared to other forums of early 21st century. It was clean due to prevention of offtopics/vogue opinions and the lack off obnoxious ads! I understand that you want to monetize. But DON'T allow online advertises to inject content here. I would understand a hand picked ad for something physics related (a book, lab equipment etc.) but some random kitchen stuff? What's next, googles that allow you to learn new language in a week, or a hot milf in my area?

Comment: @user1068352 SE is [testing ads across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/332043), and it has been a complete mess. And yeah, [clickbait/scams](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3563/65679) do appear.

Comment: Perhaps the ads team could test in a sandbox rather than with our browsers.