# Is it a good approach to report a bug with an answer to a similar question, rather than asking a new question?

Tags: discussion, answers, bug-reports

Is it a good approach to report a bug with an answer to a similar question, rather than asking a new question?

I see something like this happening here:

- [Stack Overflow for Teams is now free for up to 50 users, forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever)
- [‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​It's possible to create empty content fields - particularly question titles and bodies - on sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359283/its-possible-to-create-empty-content-fields-p/359285#359285)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bugs can be posted as answers to questions *if the company explicitly asks for it*, for example when [rolling out new features or major changes to existing functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/295232):

> #### Feedback
>
> Please leave any feedback or bug reports related to this release below this post. We will be reviewing responses on this post for one month following Phase 3 (March 23, 2021). After March 23rd, please ask a new question to report any new issues.

One topic with 121 answers is much easier to handle than 121 separate questions, both for the developers/testers and for users not interested in the topic; the latter only have to skip one question on the Meta homepage, not several.

One should note that this is the **exception**, not the rule. The question about empty content is even more exceptional; this time the *community* decided on an organized bug hunting spree.

Generally speaking, a new bug needs a new question. If you have found a bug which is very similar to an existing one, and likely caused by the same error, it's good to link them together rather than posting a new question, but it's best to do so either:

- by posting a comment describing what you found
- by editing the question (or suggesting an edit) to add your example

Note that the bug has been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) which means they decided they won't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially to a point, folks find having all the feedback for a new feature release in one place easier. After a while though the value of this diminishes.

Basically if it's a 'new' feature answers on an announcement post is fine. After a month or two, a new post is a better idea

If it's something critical post a new question - we have a few options to speed things up.