# Post about teams mentions minimize *this* prompt - what prompt, exactly?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

In the post [about teams being free now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362203/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-free-for-up-to-50-users-forever?cb=1) it states

> If you don’t belong to any teams, there will be a prompt to start a team, which can be minimized.

what is this referencing? I can not find a way to minimize *this* prompt to start a team.

[image: prompt to start team]

so what is it referencing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that *is* the minimized form.

The full version is a larger box with a Teams prompt:

[image: full Teams prompt]

Clicking the X in the corner of it results in what's in your screenshot.

Comment: ah, i see, thats probably it.