# Stack overflow for teams ad

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, advertising

For some time now I keep seeing this on most of the SE sites I visit:

[image]

While I admit that this is a useful piece of information, I still want to find out how many more days will I be seeing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That prompt will remain until you log in and minimize it, like mentioned in the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362203/369802) of said prompt:

> If you don’t belong to any teams, there will be a prompt to start a team, which can be minimized.

To do so, press the X in the upper right corner:

[image]

Again, you need to be logged in to do this. If you're visiting anonymously, you're out of luck and will probably keep seeing this for as long as the company wants to show it. But once you've done that, all that will remain is a single link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The good part is that if I do it on at least one SE site where I have an account, then it automatically changes in the same way on all sites, including those where i do not have an account.

Comment: It looks like the OP has a very limited height causing a scrollbar to appear that hides the X .... ?

Comment: @rene hence the screenshot, proving there is supposed to be one and where to find it ;)

Comment: @rene I might be misremembering but I believe I took this screenshot on a site where I do not have an account, so there should not be any X present