# NSFW video and annoying animated advertising on Music SE

Tags: support, etiquette, advertising

I'm seeing this annoying animated advertisement on Music SE. Somehow saving the gif was impossible, so I recreated it as well as I could from screenshots (first image). The actual thing is even more jumpy and annoying, and the black button changes size a couple of times.

[image: GIF of animated ad]

---

[image: screenshot of video ad]

**Update**: I was just shown a video (not a gif animation) advertisement for fitness clothing; as you can see in this screenshot (second image), the camera angles are far from subtle, and the whole video borders on being NSFW.

Comment: [Get](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/332043) [an](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331960/332043) [ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/332043) [blocker](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation). SE has said in the past they're going to let animated ads be a part of their horrible ad experiment

Comment: see the end of the first post of https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/issues/158 in case you need suggestions.  For safari users  in trouble, https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/

Comment: FYI, Fisher Investments is a notorious US investment fund whose name is synonymous with "underperform, sometimes lose money". [MotleyFool 2016: Three money managers failing to get the job done 1) Ken Fisher](https://www.fool.com/investing/general/2016/04/22/chances-are-youre-outperforming-these-3-well-known.aspx)

Comment: @smci I spent 30 seconds googling them and found nothing but complaints about their aggressive marketing and sales strategies :-)

Comment: I mean, ads for herbal Viagra are less disreputable and have higher customer satisfaction.

Comment: Looking forward to winning big bucks by punching a monkey!

Comment: Butt through pants isn't really NSFW but yeah, many people won't like seeing it jumping at them in a site they considered professional.

Comment: @Shadow If you passed someone's desk and saw a few seconds of it on their screen, you'd think they were watching that infamous Eric Prydz "Call On Me" video :-)

Comment: Hmm... well really need to see it as gif/vid then, as image it's really not that bad. Using dev tools of the browser you should be able to get the video source, i.e. the URL used to show it.

Comment: So you have to work on your pension and your butt. I would say that is pretty well targetted ... ;)

Comment: I had an ad for bras, complete with lots of helpful arrows to said bra. Makes your booty ad look tame

Comment: @Machavity It wasn't just booty, it was an all-areas pervy zoomfest :-)

Answer (score -151, accepted):

We do intend to display animated ads on Stack Exchange. However, jarring and wiggling ads will be blocked and removed from our properties. Thank you for reporting.

(*Editor's note:* The advertising guidelines [have since been changed](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines) to categorically disallow animated ads.)

Comment: In my own point of view, *all* animated ads are jarring, and I always see them wiggling. I may be in the wrong here, but you may want to clarify where you put the limit between acceptable animated ads and jarring animated ads, so we don't waste time reporting things you deem acceptable (and you don't waste time telling us they're acceptable). Just a few examples could be useful here.

Comment: Thanks for finally admitting open mouthed that you allow animated ads now. What about the ad content? What are the limits? Viagra ads are allowed? (I'm totally serious)

Comment: You might be interested in knowing that animated ads (not on Stack Exchange sites, but on the Internet in general) are the reason why I installed an ad blocker, and why I basically never turn it off for any site. Your answer has told me that it would be VERY unwise for me to change my policy w.r.t. SE. In other words, your decision to allow animated ads is one reason why you're not getting any ad revenue from me. (Not the only one, but it might be the only one for other users),

Comment: What there is still ads? Why m'I not getting any since I reported NSFW ads? Did they black list because I reported too mutch ads? Did you black listed me?

Comment: @xdtTransform  Which site are you talking about? Visit others maybe? Where you have less than 200 rep

Comment: @ankii, that's suspicious. For all sites, with less than 200 rep, I have No ads. My selenium is get clicking all HNQ first page with a small account, using edge (no adblock on edge) and nothing cames up. Either they black listed my self or disable for french user.

Comment: @xdtTransform Only some of the sites show ads. Try clicking on a random question on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If you're going to compromise on this, when can we expect you to compromise on ads with audio or video, background ads, or popups? Where are the limits? _Are there any?_

Comment: So much for years of promising this will never happen. Too bad stevvve isn't around anymore.

Comment: "*jarring and wiggling ads will be blocked and removed from our properties*" - **only when reported by users and then followed up manually by staff**, as previously noted here?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333536/inappropriate-weight-loss-ad-on-the-workplace-elu-and-travel/333538#comment1089326_333538

Comment: A post by staff had to be edited twice? Way to set an example, guys.

Comment: When was the policy on animated ads changed? I though they were previously not allowed.

Comment: FYI, they've stated this [a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network#comment1076849_329818). This isn't a new policy change, nor one that had gone unnoticed. /cc @Shadow

Comment: @PrincessOlivia it wasn't clear if they're going to allow animated ads. They never replied to such questions and kept it all very vague. So the fact they say it out aloud "We now allow animated ads" is totally new. Same with viagra ads: as you see they aren't going to reply, and I suspect that at some point we'll see such ads, followed by "Hello, yes we allow viagra ads now across the network. Thanks for watching those ads." BTW, think you meant to reply to Steven, not me? (He asked about the policy change)

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro see Princess Olivia's comment above and my own below it.

Comment: For many years I had AdBlock. I removed it about 2 years ago, partially to help support this site, and others like it. It's just been re-installed. SE will not be getting whitelisted.

Comment: @TerryGuyton-Bradley I updated the question with a borderline-nsfw video (not animation) ad I was just shown on Music SE.

Comment: In the name of maximum traffic, SE will now solely focus cute cat pictures and porn. Enjoy!

Comment: I ask again - how is allowing animated ads consistent with claiming to care about accessibility? SE is deliberately choosing to violate WCAG 2.2.2 after claiming to be working towards full compliance.

Comment: @sonic do you have a timeline of when were they revised?

Answer (score 80):

SE has already subverted their [no animated ads policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387222/5958455) in the past few months, which finally led me into installing AdBlock Plus.

I think it's time for everyone to enable their ad blocker on SE now, had anyone disabled it before.

Oh what? NSFW video??? Are we going to see [more than 15k bottles of Viagra from Kenya](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322152/350567)??? Where's your stand? **Please, Stack Exchange, seriously, hold your ground on the "no animated ads" policy.**

Comment: Is discussing the merits of AB+ versus uBo on-topic for this comment chain? If so, I'm going pro-uBo

Comment: @JohnDvorak I wasn't a fan of blockers before and the only item in my knowledge was AB+. Thanks for the suggestion of uBO.

Comment: as I commented above too.. https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/issues/158 @JohnDvorak It has some suggestions and comparisons in the end.

Comment: @iBug companies can pay AB+ to have their ads whitelisted

Comment: @OrangeDog ... which is an optional setting that literally takes 2 clicks to disable (Settings -> uncheck "Allow Acceptable Ads"). I for one like that functionality (even though I no longer have it enabled either), because there are rules about how those "acceptable adds" should look, and it motivates advertisers to make their adds less obnoxious.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker in principal many prefer to use a plugin that doesn't have vested commercial interests. Many other plugins have also ended up being sold and converted to malware.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker It's optional for now.  How long until it's not, and you get, "acceptable ads", whether you like it or not?  It's not a good idea to trust a company to stay the course.  I didn't think they'd allow ads in the first place.

Comment: I find that Privacy Badger does an acceptable job of blocking ads.  When SE changed from hosting its own ads to using an ad network, Privacy Badger decided that it was time to start blocking those ads.

Comment: No, they didn't. I'm really not on their side right now, but your link _specifically_ mentions Stack Overflow _only_. Let's not lose sight of objectivity even if there's a hell of a lot of ill-will about.

Comment: @roganjosh What about [another link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213770/350567)?

Comment: When did SE start allowing animated ads?

Comment: @iBug that link doesn't really show any announcement, other than Terry's answer above, since it just refers back to this question.

Comment: Don't install Adblock Plus, get uBlock Origin instead. It's lighter and does more to protect you. In particular, ABP accepts bribes to let some ads through.

Comment: @JAD That answer was only recently edited by Shadow after seeing the answer under. It remained an announcement de facto for years before this thread.

Comment: **Go with Privacy Badger.**  It auto blocked SE’s new ads based on the presence of trackers.  It ignored their previous static ads.  Just right.  (To oversimplify, once it sees the same resource on three different domains, it recognizes it as a tracker and blocks it.)

Comment: @Stevoisiak Possibly [before end of June](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network#comment1076849_329818).

Comment: @Wildcard: Privacy Badger and uBlock Origin mostly complement each other.

Comment: @einpoklum Suit yourself, but [uBlock origin uses some pretty shady tactics themselves](https://www.troyhunt.com/ad-blockers-are-part-of-the-problem/).

Comment: @Wildcard: At that link, a person who published an ad complained about the ad getting blocked. He claimed that since it's a "sponsorship" and a "sponsorship message", it shouldn't be be blocked. While I understand he might believe that - it's not a reasonable expectation. So, nothing shady.

Comment: @einpoklum you clearly didn’t read the article if that’s what you think.  Troy Hunt is part of the solution, not part of the problem.  I won’t debate this further; as I said, suit yourself.  The fact that *AdBlock Plus reversed their decision* after that article was published should be telling.  I prefer using PrivacyBadger exclusively; who knows how many other websites are *complying* with AdBlock Plus’s guidelines but being unfairly targeted anyway due to deliberate human intervention.  Dig a little deeper and you’ll see what I mean.

Comment: @Wildcard: It is telling. AdBlock Plus selectively blocks ads, uBlock Origin blocks ads. I understand there are reasons why some believe the first alternative is better, but - there's no basis for you calling the second approach "shady".

Answer (score 5):

I work for a large US-based organization and regularly use an ad-blocker with some limited white-listing. Ads like the second example (fitness attire) would be considered objectionable by some of my colleagues.

Stack Exchange really needs to be aware of what advertising they are allowing on the network.