# Does downvoting an answer on Meta cost rep now?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes, meta

I recently (an hour or so ago) downvoted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334144/272106) (which had been at a score of 0 before my downvote, in case that's relevant), and I saw my Meta.SE rep go from 101 to 100 (and got a notification in the "trophy" menu that I had lost 1 rep point).

This is contrary to what I had previously believed: that downvotes in Meta cost no rep either for the votee **or** for the voter. Did that change recently?

Comment: I see. FWIW you probably can dupe-close to desired question yourself [as explained eg here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773). In this case, both mine and your dupe targets will be shown here - if this is important to get rid of mine you can flag for moderator or ask someone with gold [tag:support] badge to edit the list

Comment: I don't care if yours is shown as well, but I appear to not have enough Meta.SE reputation to vote to close my own question (?!): the only buttons I see are "share", "edit", "delete", and "flag". I guess I'll flag for moderator attention, though given [recent events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper), there might not be that many mods active right now...

Comment: nono, flag -> close -> duplicate...

Comment: @gnat - Ah, got it! Thanks, dupe-closing it now. I'm too used to having 20k+ rep, as Stack Overflow is the only site I really participate in, so I've forgotten how the UI looks at low rep levels. *grin*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Welcome to [Meta Stack Exchange](/help/whats-meta), which is a *separate* site in the network with its own [reputation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), functioning exactly like a main site like [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (though privilege levels might be a bit different). So just like on Stack Overflow, downvoting answers costs reputation.

On per-site Metas like [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), you cannot lose (or earn) reputation; that reputation is always synchronized from the account on the corresponding main site. The following section from the [Stack Overflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) is 'missing' from the one used [here](/help/whats-meta):

> #### If you have an account on Stack Overflow, you have an account on its meta site.
>
> You do not need to create a separate account for meta; once you are logged in on Stack Overflow, you are also logged in and may post on its meta site.
>
> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

Comment: So the name was confusing me. Now that I know that despite the "meta" in the name, this is not a metasite *per se* because it's not a meta for any **one** site, the fact that it functions just like a normal site (i.e., SO) makes sense. I understand better now; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Meta Stack Exchange is different in this regard to the normal meta sites like [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).
Reputation here works the same as on normal sites.
This means you lose 1 rep when downvoting a answer.